# Cartesian product of two lists

Tags: code-golf, set-theory

#### Task

Given two lists of characters, output their Cartesian product, i.e. the list of pairings of each letter from the first list with each letter from the second list.

#### Example

`"123456"` and `"abcd"` give:

```
[["1","a"],["1","b"],["1","c"],["1","d"],["2","a"],["2","b"],["2","c"],["2","d"],["3","a"],["3","b"],["3","c"],["3","d"],["4","a"],["4","b"],["4","c"],["4","d"],["5","a"],["5","b"],["5","c"],["5","d"],["6","a"],["6","b"],["6","c"],["6","d"]]
```

#### Input

Two lists of characters or strings. The characters used will be alphanumeric `a-z, A-Z, 0-9` and a character can occur both multiple times and in both inputs at the same time.

#### Output

The Cartesian product of the input lists. That is, a list of each possible ordered pair of a character from the first list and a character from the second list. Each pair is a list or string or similar of two characters, or of two length-one strings. The output's length will be equal to the product of the lengths of the inputs.

The pairs must be listed in order; first listing the first character of the first list with the first of the second list, followed by all the pairings of the first character of the first list. The last pair consists of the last character of the first list together with the last character of the second list.

The output must be a flat list of pairs; not a 2D matrix where pairs are grouped by their first or second element.

#### Test cases

```
inputs               output

"123456", "abcd"     [["1","a"],["1","b"],["1","c"],["1","d"],["2","a"],["2","b"],["2","c"],["2","d"],["3","a"],["3","b"],["3","c"],["3","d"],["4","a"],["4","b"],["4","c"],["4","d"],["5","a"],["5","b"],["5","c"],["5","d"],["6","a"],["6","b"],["6","c"],["6","d"]]
"abc", "123"         [["a","1"],["a","2"],["a","3"],["b","1"],["b","2"],["b","3"],["c","1"],["c","2"],["c","3"]]
"aa", "aba"          [["a","a"],["a","b"],["a","a"],["a","a"],["a","b"],["a","a"]]
```

Comment: @Adám Changed. I'm having trouble though wording that repeated characters in an input string can and should cause repeated pairs in the output (assuming that's how interpret it).

Comment: @xnor maybe easier if the order of pairs is fixed?

Comment: Why does the title say "list" yet the body say "list of characters"?

Comment: Just to be sure: is `["1a", "1b", "1c", "2a", "2b", "2c", "3a", "3b", "3c"]` a valid output format?

Comment: wow. lots of amazing answers. what are the criteria for chosing an accepted answer? And should I give my own answer on es5 (the code that inspired the question in the first place?)

Comment: You tagged this as `code-golf` therefore shortest answer wins. In the event of a tie, the first answer to reach that score is usually the winner (currently [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125113/58974)). Give it another few days, at least, before accepting an answer, though, if at all. And see [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12104/58974) for guidelines on answering your own question.

Comment: @Adám ty for editing.

Comment: @Adám I assume taking the input as boxed in J allowed?

Comment: @Jonah I'd think so. That's natural for J.

Comment: @Adám, Sorry I thought you were the OP and not just the editor.  But thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

```
â
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8KL//6MNdRSMdBSMdRRMdBRMY7milRKVdBSUkkBEMohIARGpSrEA)

Answer (score 18):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 12 bytes

```hs
(<*>).map(,)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P81Ww0bLTlMvN7FAQ0fzf25iZp5tQVFmXomCRpqCUmJSspKCkqGRsZLmfwA)

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, 12 bytes

```
Tuples@{##}&
```

Takes two lists of characters as input.

Comment: Same length: `Tuples@*List` Alternatively, if arbitrary heads are allowed: `Tuples@*f`

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 4 bytes

```apl
,∘.,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wSdRx0z9HT@ZxXn5wF55oZmBo96toG5CuqGRsYmpmbqCmkK6olJySnqXBBhIBssBpSGCyVCVSWqAwA)

`,` flatten

`∘.` the Cartesian

`,` concatenation

Comment: I don't think `flatten` is a good description here, since flattening would produce the incorrect result, I think "tighten" or "reduce rank" or something similar should work. (Flattened [1,2]x[1,2] is [1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2])

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/g/6OGOYZGxiamZo8a5h5eDuQlJiWnANmR/wE)

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>30</s> 18 bytes

-12 bytes from Jordan reminding me of a way to use the spec to my advantage!

Takes lists of characters as input.

```ruby
->a,b{a.product b}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9cuUSepOlGvoCg/pTS5RCGp9n@BQppecmJOjoKWY5B7mF5uYoGGmlVyRmJRseb//xmpOTn5/8vzi3JSAA)

Comment: The specification says the input is "Two lists of characters or strings," so I don't think you need `.chars`.

Comment: It is a shame browsers dont speak ruby. Such a friendly language..

Answer (score 4):

## Octave, 32 bytes

```matlab
@(a,b)[(a+~b')(:) (b'+~a)(:) '']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNRJ0kzWiNRuy5JXVPDSlNBI0lduy4RzFRXj/2fmFesoWRoZGxiaqako6CUmJScoqT5HwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
{∋ᵐ}ᶠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v/pRR/fDrRNqH25b8P9/tJKhkbGJqZmSjlJiUnKKUuz/KAA)

#### Explanation

Pretty self-explanatory

```
{  }ᶠ       Find all:
  ᵐ           Map:
 ∋              In
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 4 bytes

```
&[X]
```

This is just a reference to the built-in cross product operator `X`.  It works on lists of any sort, not just characters.

Answer (score 4):

## J, 3 bytes

```
,@{
```

This is the [Catalogue verb](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/curlylf) in J.  We need to Ravel (`,`) the result to make it 1 dimensional.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I19Bx6FaQT0xKVndWt3QyFj9/38A)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>45</s> <s>36</s> <s>34</s> 33 bytes

Requires Firefox. Takes both inputs as strings or as arrays of individual characters.

```js
a=>b=>[for(x of a)for(y of b)x+y]
```

- -1 byte thanks to [CalculatorFeline](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51443/calculatorfeline) spotting an errant `<space>`.

---

### Try It

```js
f=
a=>b=>[for(x of a)for(y of b)x+y]
oninput=_=>console.clear()&console.log(f(i.value)(j.value))
console.log(f(i.value="123456")(j.value="abcd"))
```

```html
<input id=i><input id=j>
```

Comment: Destructuring works on strings too.

Comment: Thanks, @Neil; forgot to update that after I changed the method I was using.

Comment: Is `x+y` a valid output format?

Comment: @Neil: That's what I was originally going to go with but, from the test cases, it appears that wouldn't be valid; rereading the output requirements, though, they seem to indicate that it might be. I'll ask for clarification to be sure.

Comment: `for (` Why is there a space?

Comment: D'oh! Don't know how that slipped past me @CalculatorFeline!

Comment: It seems you have really taken the hang of es6! I invite you to check out my es5 "answer" on my own challenge (the code that inspired my question). Pls feel free to provide improvement suggestions on it.

Comment: @alexandros84: Yeah, ES6(+) is essential if you're to stand even a remote chance of being competitive in golf - by the time you've typed `function`, you've already lost! I'll throw a few pointers on your answer later but, in the meantime, have a look at my original array mapping solution in the edit history; you should be able to just rip that off and replace the arrow functions with "real" functions.

Comment: getting an error when i try to run this in the "try it" thingy

Answer (score 3):

## [Tcl](https://www.tcl.tk), 60 bytes

```
proc p x\ y {lmap X $x {lmap Y $y {lappend l $X\ $Y}};set l}
```

Use:

```
% p {1 2 3} {a 2 2}
{1 a} {1 2} {1 2} {2 a} {2 2} {2 2} {3 a} {3 2} {3 2}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

```
*ww
```

Multiplying two strings just acts as the cartesian product.

[Test it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Aww&input=aa%0Aaba&debug=0)

Comment: The 2 Bytes solution `*E` would require to swap the order of the input strings :( https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2aE&input=%22cd%22%0A%22ab%22&debug=0

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, 18

This can be done with brace expansions:

```bash
eval echo {$1}{$2}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhfnFqiYKhjpGOskKiTpJP8P7UsMUchNTkjX6FaxbC2WsWo9v9/AA).

Answer (score 3):

## Common Lisp, 63 bytes

```
(lambda(a b)(mapcan(lambda(x)(mapcar(lambda(y)(list x y))b))a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ncu7CoAwDIXhVwk4mDN6fRqXtF0KVYo62KevR7DDB@FP4lO8ctV8xsOLVk22u2Bq4qC7ZW9HS88fzhYKlM@3PFIABxhQe@22QbptpIlmWmiFfCvj6MhTAO9f)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 39 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:[[i,j]for i in x for j in y]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaFCp9IqOjpTJys2Lb9IIVMhM0@hQgHEzAIxK2P/FxRl5pUopGmoGxoZm5iaqesoqCcmJaeoa3KBZbjg8kBRkCRQGRa5RIi@RHXN/wA)

### Alternate solution, <s>34</s> 30 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to Anders Kaseorg.*

There is a built-in for this...

```python
from itertools import*
product
```

Comment: 30 bytes: `from itertools import*;product`

Answer (score 2):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 29 bytes

```
[_l;||[_l;||?_sA,a,1|+_sB,b,1
```

This prints 2-char strings with all combinations on one line each.

### Explanation

```
   ;      Read in string A$
 _l |     Get its length as b
[    |    and kick off a FOR-loop from 1 to that
[_l;||    Do the same for B$
          Note that, while the FOR-loop may pass this code several times, the
          'read-from cmd line' is done only once.
?_sA,a,1| PRINT the character from A$ at the position of the 'a' loop counter
+_sB,a,1   concatenated with the char from B$ at the pos of the 'b' loop counter
```

Answer (score 2):

## C# 7, <s>78</s> 63 bytes

```c#
(a,b)=>$"({string.Join(",",a.SelectMany(x=>b,(x,y)=>(x,y)))})";
```

Comment: this isn't a full program nor a function

Comment: You are supposed to write a full program or a function and not snippet.

Comment: I just changed it. But many answers on this page aren't full programs or functions. Not sure why this one is singled out.

Comment: btw, this is why I don't like code golf.

Comment: Since this is a function, you can directly return the output string instead of writing it to the screen, I think that saves you ~20 bytes.

Comment: @sundar I suppose so. Thnx.

Comment: Note that some languages used here have pretty compact notation for functions. I see only [one answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125800/) on this page that clearly isn't a full program or function. It seems to be getting complained about now. I've flagged it too. And yes, PPCG's rules can take a while to get used to. I'm probably still missing some.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 2 bytes

```
Z*
```

`*` is the general operator for products and the prefix `Z` makes it the *cartesian* product and can take two strings as arguments.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P0rr/3/1xOKUNHUu9YrKKnUA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 1 byte

```
∙
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8//9Rx8z//5USk5JTlLiUDI2MTUzNlAA)

`∙` is the Cartesian product command.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
v²NFÀ}¹ø)˜
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/7NAmP7fDDbWHdh7eoXl6zv//KUWpXFWJBQA)

This is without the built-in, and undoubtedly won't be competitive.

Comment: The output For input "aba" "aa" it seems wrong

Answer (score 2):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 1 byte

```
╒
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/I/f//0dRJ//8bGhmbmJpxJSYlpwAA)

Literally only the built-in

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>5</s> 2 bytes

Japt now has a method for the Cartesian product.

Takes input as 2 arrays of character strings.

```
ïV
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=71Y=&input=WyJhIiwiYSJdLFsiYSIsImIiLCJhIl0KLVE=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 1 byte

```
*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fm18enHpiffGh5Y@aGh@1TXjUNqn80Lb/Wv///zc0MjYxNVNITEpO4QISCkA@V2IikJ8IAA) `*` does Cartesian products when given two lists.

Answer (score 2):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 81 bytes

```
listen to X
listen to Y
cut X
while X
roll X in C
cut Y in Z
while Z
say C+roll Z
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Comment: Seems like you answered the [wrong challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/190223/insert-inbetween/261396#261396)

Comment: Something weird going on, @TheThonnu, every time I edit one it updates the other, too. I've given up for the day, will try again in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 21 bytes

```
#(for[i % j %2][i j])
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 69 bytes

```php
<?foreach($_GET[0]as$x)foreach($_GET[1]as$y)$r[]=[$x,$y];print_r($r);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vcy9CsIwFAXgvY8RMiQQwfq3xOIgQVx06RZCiG00XZJw7dAuvrVzvLo5fHA4cE4OuewPOeTKAySw4HOCcYgP9lL2cm3PR8VlRe1JtY3WpCaCrNAabdAW7YgRmjhMN9ShHnlijCz3BN51gf0O9NK4J534f1l/y5lT0KbRdBJ0NjLDEEcLjAKXpbxjWnQ48B8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Cheddar](http://cheddar.vihan.org/), 52 bytes

```
a->b->a.chars.map(i->b.chars.map(i&(+))).reduce((+))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ITUlJLPpfUJSZV6LxP1HXLknXLlEvOSOxqFgvN7FAIxMogsxV09DW1NTUK0pNKU1O1QBx/mtqKBkaGZuYmikBWYlJySlKmv8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 49 bytes

```
.(?=.*¶(.+))
$1$&¶
¶¶.+
¶
.(?=.*(.)¶)
$1$&¶
¶.¶
¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT8PeVk/r0DYNPW1NTS4VQxW1Q9u4Dm07tE1PG0hxQaQ19DQPbUOS1QOT//8bGhmbmJpxJSYlpwAA) Takes input on separate lines. Explanation:

```
.(?=.*¶(.+))
$1$&¶
```

Each character in the first string generates a separate line prefixed by the second string.

```
¶¶.+
¶
```

The original second string is deleted.

```
.(?=.*(.)¶)
$1$&¶
```

For each character in the first string, each character in the second string generates a separate line prefixed with the first character.

```
¶.¶
¶
```

The left-over characters from the first string are deleted.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
ＦθＥη⁺ικ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBo1BTIaAoM69EwzexQCNDRyEgp7RYI1NHIVtT0/r/f0MjYxNTM67EpOSU/7pl/3WLcwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: The variables `θ` and `η` implicitly refer to the two input strings. The `Ｆ` command loops over each character of the first input, while the `Ｅ` command maps over each character of the second input concatenating the loop variable `ι` and the map variable `κ`, the result of which is implicitly printed on separate lines.

Comment: This seems to be 19 bytes.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Charcoal has its own [code page](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page).

Answer (score 1):

## q/kdb+, 5 bytes

**Solution:**

```
cross           / yup, there's a built-in to do exactly this
```

**Example:**

```
q)"123456"cross"abcd"
"1a"
"1b"
"1c"
"1d"
"2a"
"2b"
"2c"
"2d"
"3a"
"3b"
"3c"
"3d"
"4a"
"4b"
...etc
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 29 bytes

```r
function(x,y)outer(x,y,paste)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQqdSM7@0JLUIxNIpSCwuSdX8n6ZhaGWmk5NaAhQvjja0MonV/A8A)

Note that R matrix are filled by column, so the result is in the order dictated by the spec.

If allowed to have `factors` for input and output, there is a built-in... but one needs to extract the resulting levels from the factor so in the end it would be more than 29 bytes.

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 11 bytes

```r
interaction
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/M68ktSgxuSQzP@9/TmpZak6xRppGGlAgv0jD0MpMUwfKzkktASosjja0MonV1NT8DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 21 bytes

```
~\:a;{a{[.;1$]}%\;}%`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/vy7GKtG6OrE6Ws/aUCW2VjXGulY14f//aEMFo1iFaGMFk1gA)

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 101

Inputs A1, B1.

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(Flatten(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)&MID(B1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(B1)),1)),"(.)(.)
```

### How it Works

- Turn string into character array. The first is vertical, the second is horizontal because of how we call `SEQUENCE`.
- Concatenate every permutation of one letter from each string. (Because one is vertical and the other is horizontal.
- Flatten into array
- Extract first and second character by Regex
- I considered delimiting by commas and splitting, but that would have required more work if the first string had a comma (or whatever delimiting character).

### Notes

- `Flatten` is an undocumented function that turns any range into a column array.

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 24 bytes

```scala
for(x<-_;y<-_)yield(x,y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFBQzZWSmqaQFh0Sa6URnFoIpHUglKatHYihEaITohlr@z8tv0ijwkY33roSSGhWZqbmpGhU6FRq/i8oyswrycnTSNNQMjQyNjE1U9JRSkxKTlHS1OSq/Q8A)

I love for comprehensions.

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 8 bytes

```
L*,€€+BF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HS@dR0xog0nZy@6@Sk5iblJKoYGinZGhkbGJqpmSnlJiUnKLE5c@FJAcUUgKrQBdPBKtPBAr/BwA)

### How it works

```
L*,		; Create an anonymous function that returns the entire stack
		; Example inputs: 	"abc" "123"
	€	; Over each char:	["1" "abc"]
	 €	;   Over each char:	["1" "a"]
	  +	;     Concatenate	"a1"
		;   This returns	["a1" "a2" "a3"]
		; This returns		[[["a1" "a2" "a3"] ["b1" "b2" "b3"] ["c1" "c2" "c3"]]]
	BF	; Flatten		["a1" "a2" "a3" "b1" "b2" "b3" "c1" "c2" "c3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
Π
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiIiwizqAiLCIiLCJcIjEyMzQ1NlwiLCBcImFiY2RcIiJd)

Vyxal's built ins are fun!

Answer (score 1):

## TypeScript Type System, 111 bytes

```typescript
type X<A,B>=A extends[infer F,...infer R]?[...B extends[any,...infer V]?[[F,B[0]],...X<[F],V>]:[],...X<R,B>]:[]
```

[Test it at the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBAjFYEYJ4BcCmBnMJgChMLgByTAA0AeAQQBoAhAPgF4ywkAPZAOwBMUBtASzYBmSAE5gAYhQB00-kNEAlALoB+btMlUmrJJx4BDNnCkzBIsADUV3bhKrcADIsXHJpG8-M1FALm7P1pPLUXr6K2Dj4hAAqqAgQYHTEJNwQFGAATGkAzM5g3ABEZPlp+VT5ijSYwMBgtQB6yhEEYDEoCOkJSdwArCUAbMVgAOwlABzlaQVFJWUVVTX1jUA)

My old, more intuitive answer is unfortunately invalid due to the challenge requiring an array of tuples rather than an array of arrays of tuples. This complicated mess, on the other hand, seems to be shorter than using the old version and defining a flatten-type.

```typescript
type X<A, B> = A extends [ // generic type X takes tuples A and B
  infer F,                 // from A, get first (F)
  ...infer R               // and rest (R)
]
  ? [                                // push:
      ...B extends [any, ...infer V] //   get first and rest (V) from B
        ? [                          //   push:
            [F, B[0]],               //     [ F, B[0] ]
            ...X<[F], V>             //     recurse with [F], V
          ]
        : [],
      ...X<R, B>                     //   recurse with R, B
    ]
  : [];
```

### TypeScript Type System, 57 bytes

This is technically invalid for this specific challenge, but I'm leaving it here since it is more practical for other challenges where cartesian product is used.

```typescript
type P<A,B>={[I in keyof A]:{[J in keyof B]:[A[I],B[J]]}}
```

[Test it at the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBArA7GBGCeAXApgZzCYAoLj4AdkwAFAHgEEAaAIQD4BeAbwG0BJMASwDswBrZeAHsAZmHIBdAFwsAUpx78ho6lObk24msxnjxAXz048hMABU0iAIxh6JUs0uUwAJicBmTWGYAict6fe1N7itFjAwGCRAHoA-LgEROaoiM42dswQAQBs-mBQAQAcwU4+fgFBIWER0XFAA)

Pretty simple but I'll leave an explanation anyway for those who don't know any TypeScript:

```typescript
type P<A, B> = {                 // generic type P takes tuple types A and B
  [I in keyof A]: {              //   for index i in A:
    [J in keyof B]: [A[I], B[J]] //     for index j in B: tuple [A[i], B[j]]
  }                              //   end
}                                // end
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 35 bytes

```javascript
a=>b=>a.flatMap(x=>b.map(y=>[x,y]))
```

```js
f=
a=>b=>a.flatMap(x=>b.map(y=>[x,y]))

document.write(`<pre style="font-size: 1rem">${[
  "f([1, 2, 3])(['a', 'b', 'c']) ",
  "f([2, 4, 6, 8])([1, 3, 5, 7]) ",
  "f(['A', 'B'])(['c', 'd', 'e'])",
].map(test => `${test} &rarr; ${JSON.stringify(eval(test))}`).join("\n")}</pre>`)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ṗ
```

Built-in. Takes input in reversed order.

##### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 21 bytes

```
a^b=permutedims(a).*b
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6FlsT45JsC1KLcktLUlMyc4s1EjX1tJIgcjfbCooy80py8jQ0kvNzclKTSzSUDI2MTUzNlDTj4CKJSckpSpqa0VaxmlyY6oGyyIqB2vGoTUQ1NxGqFOIamIsB)

Takes input as character arrays, returns length-2 strings. Frustratingly, one-byte `'` operator doesn't work with text, so we have to `permutedims` instead. Still a few bytes shorter than a nested `for` loop.

While this technically returns a 2D matrix, which the OP doesn't want, it **does** support 1D-indexing (as demonstrated in test cases on ATO), and so is perfectly usable as a flat list. However, this requirement probably invalidates the built-in answer, as Julia flattens the Matrix in column-major order, giving a different result sequence:

### [Julia](https://julialang.org), 17 bytes

```
Iterators.product
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBojTbpaUlaboWGz1LUosSS_KLivUKivJTSpNLIOI38wqKMvNKcvI0kvNzclKTSzTSNJQMjYxNTM2UdJQSk5JTlDQ1o61iNbmwqANKAxUBVeNTkwg2JxGqBGLrggUQGgA)

Comment: 15 bytes: `a^b=[a...;;].*b` (needs julia 1.7+)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 2 bytes

```
ᵐ~
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6Fksebp1Qt6Q4KbkYKrDgpn60kqGRsYmpmZKOglJiUnKKUixXNIgB4gNlINxEiGyiUixEHwA)

```
ᵐ   Map
 ~  Any of
```

A port of [@Fatalize's Brachylog answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125176/9288).

Answer (score 1):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 92 bytes

```
fi:?v~:f(?v1-00.
-10.\i{:{:}$}$p1
1~v?gf:11~/.27oa$<v!?ge:+1$
  \:fgo$:ego$1+ $/;
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiZmk6P3Z+OmYoP3YxLTAwLlxuLTEwLlxcaXs6ezp9JH0kcDFcbjF+dj9nZjoxMX4vLjI3b2EkPHYhP2dlOisxJFxuICBcXDpmZ28kOmVnbyQxKyAkLztcbiAgICAgICAgICAiLCJpbnB1dCI6IjQgNTAgNTEgNjUgMzYgMyA0OCA0OSA1MCIsInN0YWNrIjoiIiwic3RhY2tfZm9ybWF0IjoibnVtYmVycyIsImlucHV0X2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMifQ==)

Each list should be prefixed by it's length

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 29 bytes

```
map(split(""))|[combinations]
```

Uses [combinations](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#combinations,combinations(n)) builtin.

Sample Run

```
$ jq -Mc  'map(split(""))|[combinations]' <<< '["123456","abcd"]'
[["1","a"],["1","b"],["1","c"],["1","d"],["2","a"],["2","b"],["2","c"],["2","d"],["3","a"],["3","b"],["3","c"],["3","d"],["4","a"],["4","b"],["4","c"],["4","d"],["5","a"],["5","b"],["5","c"],["5","d"],["6","a"],["6","b"],["6","c"],["6","d"]]

$ echo -n 'map(split(""))|[combinations]' | wc -c
  29
```

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 55 bytes

```
f(a,b)==concat[[[a.x,b.y]for y in 1..#b]for x in 1..#a]
```

some results

```
(15) -> f("123456","abcd")
   (15)
   [[1,a], [1,b], [1,c], [1,d], [2,a], [2,b], [2,c], [2,d], [3,a], [3,b],
    [3,c], [3,d], [4,a], [4,b], [4,c], [4,d], [5,a], [5,b], [5,c], [5,d],
    [6,a], [6,b], [6,c], [6,d]]
                                                Type: List List Character
(16) -> f("abc","123")
   (16)  [[a,1],[a,2],[a,3],[b,1],[b,2],[b,3],[c,1],[c,2],[c,3]]
                                                Type: List List Character
(17) -> f("aa","aba")
   (17)  [[a,a],[a,b],[a,a],[a,a],[a,b],[a,a]]
                                                Type: List List Character
```

Answer (score 0):

## APL NARS 8 chars

```
{,⍺∘.,⍵}
```

Copy from https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125115/58988  test

```
f←{,⍺∘.,⍵}
'123456' f 'abcd'
 1a 1b 1c 1d 2a 2b 2c 2d 3a 3b 3c 3d 4a 4b 4c 4d 5a 5b 5c 5d 6a 6b 6c 6d
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 48 bytes

```
L-R:-findall([A,B],(member(A,L),member(B,L)),R).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/30c3yEo3LTMvJTEnRyPaUccpVkcjNzU3KbVIw1HHR1MHynYCsjV1gjT1/tvrKkQb6hjpGMfqBukolBdllqRqgMQB)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 1 byte

```
×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//8PT//6PVM9R11FOBOAeK89VjuaLVy8EsHfUiqGiKeiwA)

Gotta love built-ins.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 2 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 1.65 bytes

```
Z!
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaLohQhDCh_wXqlxKTkFCUuJUMjYxNTMyWIMAA)

#### [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 2 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 1.65 bytes

```
zS
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaLqoIhDCh_waZopcSk5BQlHQUlQyNjE1MzpViIDAA)

Built-in solutions.

Answer (score 0):

## awk, 101 bytes

it's verbose but doesn't involve cryptic BS

```
echo '123456 abcd' |
```

---

```
awk 'function ___(_,__) { gsub(".","\\&& ",__)gsub(".",__,_); return _ 
     }$++NF = ___($++_, $++_)'
```

---

```
123456 abcd 1a 1b 1c 1d 2a 2b 2c 2d 3a 3b 3c 3d 4a 4b 4c 4d 5a 5b 5c 5d 6a 6b 6c 6d
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 45 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYuxDsIgFEX3fsULEyR0UDdsTfwAJ@NkHB4UGgxSQ4kpafh2JNXtntxzZoUOyySfWkW4oPWwNgCDNvCqQDGMs4BzCJju1xisHx9MwM3bCP1mAnzQgalUKIqfwuV/sP5kprAuXYvH1LUyJ6vdQBeeWNnad7Wi89RQglIRDmS3PxDG6pmbXL4)

```scala
(a:String,b:String)=>for{x<-a;y<-b}yield(x,y)
```