# Cartesian product of a list with itself n times

Tags: code-golf, math, array, combinatorics

When given a a list of values and a positive integer `n`, your code should output the cartesian product of the list with itself `n` times.

For example, in pseudocode your function could be similar to:

```
for x1 in list:
    for x2 in list:
        for x3 in list:
            ...
            for xn in list:
                print x1, x2, x3, ... , xn
```

Example:

```
repeated_cart([1,2,3], 3)

1 1 1  
1 1 2  
1 1 3  
1 2 1  
1 2 2  
1 2 3  
1 3 1  
1 3 2  
1 3 3  
2 1 1  
2 1 2  
2 1 3  
2 2 1  
2 2 2  
2 2 3  
2 3 1  
2 3 2  
2 3 3  
3 1 1  
3 1 2  
3 1 3  
3 2 1  
3 2 2  
3 2 3  
3 3 1  
3 3 2  
3 3 3
```

Built in functions (or functions from imported libraries) that compute the Cartesian product or Cartesian power are not allowed due to the resulting code being somewhat boring.

Inputs and outputs should be delimited but can be taken in any reasonable method. The order the output is given does not matter but duplicates are not allowed.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nothing horribly wrong, but take some time to look at this meta post and answers.[Things to avoid when writing challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/80010)

Comment: and to follow on @JayCe 's point, you could (should) post in [The Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to get feedback before posting a question :-)

Comment: @Giuseppe Ok, I'll do that from now on, thanks :)

Comment: Borderline dupe of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/125104/194

Comment: @JoshuaMartin can we use builtins that return all n-tuples over 0...m-1?

Comment: @ngn sure but you'll need to make sure the output is in the right order

Comment: The Cartesian product is an operation on sets. Do you allow sets for I/O rather than lists?

Comment: @Jakob sets should be fine

Comment: My R program has the output in a different order than your example. You say "make sure the output is in the right order"  but what does that mean? Could you put that in the question body so it's clear for future answers?

Comment: @Giuseppe sorry, I realise now that order does not matter

Answer (score 10):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 21 bytes

```hs
l#n=mapM(\_->l)[1..n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P0c5zzY3scBXIyZe1y5HM9pQTy8v9n9uYmaegq0CSEKhoCgzr0RBRSHaUMdIxzhW2fg/AA)

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 41 bytes

```r
function(l,n)unique(t(combn(rep(l,n),n)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNHJ0@zNC@zsDRVo0QjOT83KU@jKLUALAxEmpr/0zQMrYx1jDX/AwA)

`combn` is definitely not a cartesian product built-in, as it computes all `n`-combinations of its input.

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 40 bytes

```r
function(l,n)expand.grid(rep(list(l),n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNHJ08ztaIgMS9FL70oM0WjKLVAIyezuEQjRxMoo/k/TcPQyljHWPM/AA)

`expand.grid` is probably a cartesian product built-in.

Comment: Looks like the order of permutations in your main submission is wrong.

Comment: @KirillL. is there a particular reason the order is important? I interpreted the output spec as being flexible enough to allow them in any order.

Comment: there is OP's comment "make sure the output is in the right order", I presumed "right" means same as in example.

Comment: @KirillL. Ah. Didn't see that; it's not in the body of the question so I did not know it existed! I'll ask that it gets put there for clarification.

Answer (score 6):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 146 bytes

```lisp
(defun f(l n)(if(< n 2)(loop for x in l collect(list x))(loop for a in l nconc(loop for b in(f l(1- n))collect(cons a b)))))(princ(f(read)(read)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY6xCoRADER/ZcqkuEJt72c0bmAhJMvqgX@vETnupkgxvBdGrG7tPGkt@nEoGZypKr3hGJksokGj40B1GCTMiuyU1o6D/4D5AVzC5dcu2ZLCaHjlY/7qCW1pLHyHWq/pKPUyr/xc5tw0YMTEmC4)

ungolfed

```lisp
(defun nloops (lst n)
  (if (< n 1)
      '(())
      (if (< n 2)
          (loop for x in lst collect (list x))
          (loop for a in lst
                nconc (loop for b in (nloops lst (1- n))
                            collect (cons a b))))))
```

Comment: typically we suggest waiting for other submissions before posting one of your own :-)

Comment: @Giuseppe Ok, thanks  for the advice :)

Comment: I should say, it's technically not required anywhere but you'll accumulate random downvotes (as you already have) which is unfortunate considering this is a perfectly reasonable answer.

Comment: @Giuseppe i'll keep that in mind.

Comment: you don't have to have the print statement in the submission, since a function is allowed

Comment: so: [96](https://tio.run/##RYsxDsMwDAO/wi3U0MHNms8kigUYEGzDad7vKuhQDhwOd@rl6nPyzHZXGB1VWIwbKpIspAi9tQ5rAztKRRjaqv7pEZQGZ3pFLNrcs34Y0hXFIc8m@ygRGUfeT/n9gxPeWAXrFw)

Comment: [90](https://tio.run/##NYwxCgMxEAO/oi7aIoVz7X1mbd@CYW9jfOT9jkMSwagYhIq3q8/JetgrYHSEsBl3BJLcSBGe2osGXc9clfoT4y@ysDzjgiKvscGZ7utlxReTfbQoNI5Dq3z7oxMe2ATbGw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 16 bytes

```perl6
{[X,] $^a xx$^b}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1qcqlBmppdszcWVW6mglpyfkqpg@786OkInVkElLlGhokIlLqn2v15BaYlCWn6RAkiBhoKGoY6RjrGmjoKxguZ/AA)

### Expnded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with placeholder parameters $a and $b

  [X,]         #reduce using Cross meta op combined with comma op

    $^a xx $^b # list repeat $a, by $b times
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>18</s> 12 bytes

```apl
{⍺[↑,⍳⍵⍴≢⍺]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@/@lHvruhHbRN1HvVuftS79VHvlkedi4BisbX/3R61TcAtzfWobypQgaGCkYKxgomCG5BU@A8A)

-6 bytes thanks to @ngn !

Comment: you [can](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/165664/cartesian-product-of-a-list-with-itself-n-times#comment400767_165664) use `⍳` with a vector argument to generate indices and then `⍺[ ]` to get the corresponding values

Comment: I got a `RANK ERROR` when I tried to do that.

Comment: [`⍺[↑,⍳⍵⍴≢⍺]`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v/f7VHbhOpHvbuiH7VN1HnUu/lR79ZHvVsedS4CisXW/n/UNxWowFDBSMFYwUTBDUgq/AcA)

Comment: the only catch is with ⍵=1, in that case ⍳ returns a plain vector, not a vector of nested length-1 vectors as one would expect; it's one of those bugs that never get fixed, for backwards-compatibility reasons

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://github.com/ngn/k), 10 bytes

```
{x@+!y##x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqrrCQVuxUlm5ovZ/WrShgpGCsbVx7H8A)

`{` `}` is a function with arguments `x` and `y`

`#x` the length of `x`

`y##x` the length of `x` repeated `y` times

`!y##x` all length-y tuples over 0,1,...,length(x)-1 as a transposed matrix

`+` transpose

`x@` elements of `x` at those indices

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>69</s> 58 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,n:n and[v+[i]for v in f(a,n-1)for i in a]or[[]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcnBCoAgDADQX9kxaR3UW9CXjB0WIgk1RUTo6y2v75W3XVndGPG45TmDgKDuCqKB@kqJY67QISnE5Z/NmglpgnCuRMyj1KTtf7Lo0DN6Mz4)

Takes a list `a` and an integer `n`; returns a list of lists.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 33 bytes

```perl
say for glob(join',',("{$_}")x<>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIhLb9IIT0nP0kjKz8zT11HXUdDqVolvlZJs8LGTvP/f0MdIx1jLuN/@QUlmfl5xf9183L@6/qa6hkYGgAA)

Comment: Nice! So many answers have been able to utilise this lately! You can save 2 bytes with a bit of juggling: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19FyVZJR8m6OLHSxqE6WkOpWiW@VkmzwsYutlaJS8nu/39DHSMdYy7jf/kFJZn5ecX/dfNy/uv6muoZGBoAAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 72 bytes

```
R-1-R.
L-N-R:-O is N-1,L-O-M,findall([H|T],(member(H,L),member(T,M)),R).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P0jXUDdIj8tH1083yErXXyGzWMFP11DHR9df11cnLTMvJTEnRyPaoyYkVkcjNzU3KbVIw0PHR1MHyg7R8dXU1AnS1Ptvr6sQbahjpGMcq2usG6SjUF6UWZKqAZIBAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 53 bytes

```ruby
f=->l,n{n<2?l:l.flat_map{|i|f[l,n-1].map{|j|[i,*j]}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y5HJ686z8bIPscqRy8tJ7EkPjexoLomsyYtGiijaxirB@Zn1URn6mhlxdbW1v4vUEiLjjbUMdIxjgWi/wA)

Recursive approach, not so short, but guaranteed to be free of any built-ins.

It's tempting to use permutation methods, but this probably doesn't count, and the docs actually state no guarantees of the order correctness, although seems to work in practice:

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 35 bytes

```ruby
->l,n{[*l.repeated_permutation(n)]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5HJ686WitHryi1IDWxJDUlviC1KLe0JLEkMz9PI08ztvZ/gUJadLShjpGOcSwQ/QcA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```
³;þẎƊ’¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//wrM7w77huo7GiuKAmcKh//9bMSwyLDNd/zM)

### Explanation

```
³;þẎƊ’¡
³;þẎ    **Implements** the cartesian product of a value with the input
    Ɗ   Groups those together
     ’¡ Repeat (n-1) times
```

Comment: Look at OP's comment :p

Comment: My comment to which I brought it up is: "I'm also assuming builtins for the entire challenge are also disalowed," so I just assumed this is okay.

Comment: Well, let's wait for OP then

Comment: @Zacharý sorry, the cartesian power function isn't allowed

Comment: There, I fixed it to not use the cartesian power built-in

Comment: Is `þ` allowed if it is a cartesian product quick? If it's not `€Ɱ` works

Comment: **Outer** product

Comment: The portion that's doing the work is `;þ`.

Comment: Technically `×þ` is an outer product. The outer product is just the cartesian product with the resulting pairs multiplied, so `þ` is better described as a cartesian product imo.

Comment: It's called `table`.  And it can be done without generating the cartesian product.

Comment: `[[dyadic_link(link, (u, v)) for u in iterable(x, make_range = True)] for v in iterable(y, make_range = True)]`, that code is the relevant Jelly code. Nowhere does it calculate the cartesian product

Comment: I don't know, two nested for loops like that is basically the definition of a cartesian product. I'm not saying you should change it though, I just think banning the built-in in this challenge is kind of unclear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78162/discussion-between-zachary-and-dylnan).

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, 19 + 135 = 154 bytes

```java
import java.util.*;
```

```java
List<List>f(Set l,int n){var o=new Stack();if(n<1)o.add(new Stack());else for(var t:l)for(var i:f(l,n-1)){i.add(t);o.add(i);}return o;}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##TZDNToQwFEbX8BR32RqmCboDZhJ3muiKpXFRoTBlSkvaC2ZCeHa8MJoxafp/T8/XTk7y0NWXVfeD8wgdrcWI2oiHPI6H8cvoCiojQ4B3qS3M8fqmAxZbd2pYqRBMoi2C5fMkPbijVd9QoqwujOe6YbZIuROyrtm/A54rExQ0zrOtCDPD/@Y6a5hJ7CHlfNZ7HfL8BtA8X7zC0Vtw@bLGcfTrF1AiDZPTNfRkyUr02rYfnyB9GzhJR9HGtmMf4AibyD3niwxnilGc2H3v2Xt5DUKGLeYu/mpRtcoTck4TeEzgaaEUxCVv2MUNZDt5@ybGBSWn1@gev70fldeAqhduRDGQHRrLzE5YYmrL@gM)

### Ungolfed

```java
List<List> f(Set l, int n) {
    var o = new Stack();
    if (n < 1)
        o.add(new Stack());
    else
        for (var t : l)
            for (var i : f(l, n - 1)) {
                i.add(t);
                o.add(i);
            }
    return o;
}
```

### Acknowledgments

- port to Java 10 thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

Comment: If you use Java 10 instead of 8, you can change `Object` and `List` in the for-each loops to `var` for -4 bytes. In addition, you can then change `Set<List>f` to `List<List>f` and `Set o=new HashSet();` to `var o=new Stack();` for an additional -1 byte. [Try it online.](https://tinyurl.com/y87lnhup)

Comment: Hmm. is leaving out types for lambdas no longer valid

Comment: @ASCII-only No, untyped lambdas are allowed. I couldn't use a lambda here because the solution uses recursion.

Comment: @Jakob ah, that's right >_>

Answer (score 2):

## Racket, 92 bytes

```lisp
(define(f l n)(if(> n 0)(apply append(map(λ(r)(map(λ(e)(cons e r))l))(f l(- n 1))))'(())))
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##NcsxDsIwDAXQvaf4KkO/ByQKO3eJ2gRFBDdyC1KXXow7cKWQImF92f7DMzfc/VIOyekN9itN4ehDVM@ABBXGwCsUJ6HLOa2o2@vIh8v8vGny/7xwmHSGh4kkkd3zWGUvdTpyP6Xha4ojdgQOT7MV2aIuAe02b9oKquvY44yL1FTyBQ)

### Ungolfed

```lisp
(define (f l n)
    (if (> n 0)
        (apply append
            (map
                (λ (r)
                    (map (λ (e) (cons e r)) l)
                )
                (f l (- n 1))
            )
        )
        '(())
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) (no external utilities), 57

```bash
printf -vn %0$1d
a=${n//0/{$2\}}
eval echo ${a//\}{/\},{}
```

Input is given as command-line parameters; 1st is `n`, 2nd is a comma-separated list.

```bash
printf -vn %0$1d         ;# Create a string of n "0"s in the variable v
a=${n//0/{$2\}}          ;# Replace each "0" with "{a,b,...m}"
eval echo ${a//\}{/\},{} ;# Replace each "}{" with "},{" and evaluate the resulting brace expansion
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhfnFqioKurYKxgqGOkY/y/oCgzryRNQbcsT0HVQMUwhSvRVqU6T1/fQL9axSimtpYrtSwxRyE1OSNfQaU6UV8/prYaiHWqa///BwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>17</s> 10 bytes

-7 bytes thanks to Jonah!

```
>@,@{@(#<)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/7Rx0HKodNJRtNP9rcilwpSZn5CsYK6QpGCoYAWkI3wTIV09MKlb/DwA)

### Original soluton:

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 17 bytes

```
]{~(##)#:#@]i.@^[
```

### How it works?

I enumerate all the `n`-digit numbers in a number system with base the length of the list.

```
            i.         - creates a list from zero to (not including)
         #@]           - the length of the list 
              @^       - to the power of
                [      - n (left argument)
   (##)                - creates a list of n times the length of the list (for the bases)
       #:              - converts all the numbers into lists of digits in the new base
]{~                    - use the digits as indices into the list
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/Y6vrNJSVNZWtlB1iM/Uc4qL/a3IpcKUmZ@QrGCukKRgqGAFpCN8EyFdPTCpW/w8A)

Comment: `>@,@{@(#<)` for 10.  You can remove the `>@` for 8 if boxed output is acceptable.  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/7Rx0HKodNJRtNP9rcqUmZ@QrGCukKRgqGCkY/wcA "J – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Oracle SQL, 177 bytes

Create a collection type (31 bytes):

```
CREATE TYPE t IS TABLE OF INT;
```

Then use the query (146 bytes):

```
WITH n(a,b,c)AS(SELECT a,b,t()FROM i UNION ALL SELECT a,b-1,c MULTISET UNION t(COLUMN_VALUE)FROM n,TABLE(n.a)WHERE b>=0)SELECT c FROM n WHERE b=0
```

Assuming that the input parameters are in the table `i` with columns `a` and `b`:

```
CREATE TABLE i (a t,b INT) NESTED TABLE a STORE AS t_a;
INSERT INTO i VALUES ( t(1,2,3), 3 );
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e06757/13)

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e06757/13/0)**:

```
|     C |
|-------|
| 1,1,1 |
| 1,1,2 |
| 1,1,3 |
| 1,2,1 |
| 1,2,2 |
| 1,2,3 |
| 1,3,1 |
| 1,3,2 |
| 1,3,3 |
| 2,1,1 |
| 2,1,2 |
| 2,1,3 |
| 2,2,1 |
| 2,2,2 |
| 2,2,3 |
| 2,3,1 |
| 2,3,2 |
| 2,3,3 |
| 3,1,1 |
| 3,1,2 |
| 3,1,3 |
| 3,2,1 |
| 3,2,2 |
| 3,2,3 |
| 3,3,1 |
| 3,3,2 |
| 3,3,3 |
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ẋœ!ṛQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//4bqLxZMh4bmbUf/Dp@G5osKl4oG84bmX//9bMSwyXf81)

Completely different method to [Adalynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55550/adalynn)'s [existing answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/165664/cartesian-product-of-a-list-with-itself-n-times/165666#165666), plus two bytes shorter, so I thought I'd post a separate answer.

The Footer in the TIO link simply runs the above link then checks to see if the result is the same as the Cartesian power builtin. Remove it to see the full output

Same as the old version is length, but more tacit.

### How it works

```
ẋœ!ṛQ - Main link. Takes a list l on the left and n on the right
ẋ     - Repeat l n times; Call this m
   ṛ  - Right; Yield the right argument n
 œ!   - Yield all permutations of m of length n
    Q - Remove duplicates
```

The previous answer, `ẋ⁹œ!Q` used a `2-0, 2, 1` chain, where the `⁹` was necessary to prevent the `œ!` chaining to the `ẋ`. In this version, we have a `2, 2, 2, 1` chain. As it is at the start of the chain, the special `2,2,2` pattern is matched, meaning we execute the first three dyads, then deduplicate whatever that results in.

For three dyads `x (f g h) y`, we calculate `(x f y) g (x h y)` with this `2,2,2` pattern. `f` here is `ẋ`, meaning we repeat the list in `x` `y` times. `h` is `ṛ`, which takes two arguments and returns the right one `y`. Therefore, we're passing the repeated list to `œ!` on the left and `y` on the right, thus getting the permutations of length `y`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 38 bytes

```matlab
@(x,n)x(dec2base(0:n^numel(x)-1,n)-47)
```

Anonymous function that takes a row vector of values and an integer.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0InT7NCIyU12SgpsThVw8AqLy6vNDc1R6NCU9cQKKdrYq75P00j2tBAR8EIiI2B2MQgFsjQ/A8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 61 bytes

```bash
N=$1
shift
IFS=,
printf echo\\t%${N}s ""|sed "s/ /{$*},/g"|sh
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/389WxZCrOCMzrYTL0y3YVoeroCgzryRNITU5Iz8mpkRVpdqvtlhBSammODVFQalYX0G/WkWrVkc/HSgC1P7f@L/Rf8P/BgA) I found repeating strings and joining lists with commas surprisingly hard to do in bash.

Answer (score 1):

## [Javascript (Node)](https://nodejs.org/en/), 75 bytes

```
c=(m,n,a,i)=>a.length-n?m.map((_,j)=>c(m,n,[...a,m[j]],i+1)):console.log(a)
```

Recursive function which outputs the list to the console. Where `a` is an empty array and `i` is 0 (not sure if this still qualifies):

```
c([1,2,3], 3, [], 0);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpBCsIwEAXQ68zg72DtTqkeJAQZYqgJyaS0xetHcft4WT@6hy2tx2DtFXsPM1UYFInnu0qJthzvwR5Vqq5ET@Sfh/9xIqKoLnuPdBqZr6HZ3kqU0hZS7oHciAsmjwnO48y3/gU)

Comment: I think you would have to do `(m,n,a=[],i=0)=>`

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 52 bytes

```javascript
c=>g=(n,...l)=>n?c.map(w=>g(n-1,...l,w)):print(...l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpLCoAgEADQ68yACeYuGDtItBD7YJ9JVIpOb@H28TZ72@SiD7lJwU9zPC/e57csVByZlYCFlPJAMtw7edoAz8/AjaouHsQuRM8ZaisLDEq0Qo8IGssH)

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 26 bytes

```
q~(_"m*:e_"*\'_*@\~W$~:p];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7BOI14pV8sqNV5JK0Y9Xsshpi5cpc6qINb6//9oQwUjBeNYBWMA)

If only CJam had one character commands for cartesian product and flattening.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
.nM**
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy/PV0vr//9oQx0FIx0F41gA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
ẋf⁰↔U
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiIiwi4bqLZuKBsOKGlFUiLCIiLCJbMSwyLDNdXG4zIl0=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 46 bytes

```
(l,n)->matrix(#l^n,n,i,j,l[i--\#l^(n-j)%#l+1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcjBCoAgDADQXxlIsNF2iM71I1ZggTGxIeKhv7fe8ZVQVe7SIyzQMbORrE9oVV90@TA2Vk6cvYpsf6BJosHlcdqpl6rWMKIPDCfDtTPMRP0D)