# Print coordinates of an NxN grid

Tags: code-golf, grid

Question: Print out all the coordinates of a NxN grid. Preferably in C, however other languages also accepted

**Input**: N (integer)

**Output**: for N=3, a 3x3 grid:

```
0,0
1,0
2,0
0,1
1,1
2,1
0,2
1,2
2,2
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This is the start of a good question. I couldn't find a duplicate from a quick search, though I might be mistaken. One thing I'd suggest is to specify the **input** and **output**. I assume that the input is an integer `N`. Is the output a list of tuples, a list of strings, should it be printed? Does it need to be separated by a comma?

Comment: Are we allowed to return a list instead of printing them? Is any order acceptable (i.e. `[[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]]` instead of what you have above)? Can the output have 1-indexed coordinates instead of 0-indexed?

Comment: Also, see https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8066/71420 -- suggest not to ask about doing it in C if any language is acceptable.

Comment: Can we start at (1,1) instead of (0,0) ?

Comment: @sergiol must be started at 0,0

Comment: @KevinCruijssen list is acceptable

Comment: Is the input the dimensions of the grid?

Comment: Is there a particular order they have to be in or is any order fine?

Comment: Can't decide whether this is a dupe of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/165664/cartesian-product-of-a-list-with-itself-n-times) (just hardcode \$n=2\$) or [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125104/cartesian-product-of-two-lists) (just duplicate the argument instead of taking two distinct), but probably both.

Comment: Nice find on the dupe. Would have taken me forever to track that down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>83</s> 51 bytes

Saved 32 bytes and fixed output order thanks to Kevin Cruijssen.

```c
i;f(n){for(i=0;i<n*n;)printf("%d,%d\n",i++%n,i/n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOk0jT7M6Lb9II9PWwDrTJk8rz1qzoCgzryRNQ0k1RUc1JSZPSSdTW1s1TydTP0/TuvZ/bmJmngZQj4YxiAcA)

I'm by no means a C programmer (or C golfer), but I thought I'd give it a try. Should the main be included in the byte count?

Comment: [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOk0jT7M6Lb9II9PWwDrTJk8rz1qzoCgzryRNQ0k1RUc1JSZPSSdTW1s/TydTNU/TuvZ/bmJmngZQj4YxiAcA) :) (And no, main method doesn't have to be included. For Java, C, C#, etc. etc. we allows functions instead of full programs, since full programs are quite verbose and doesn't add anything to the actual solution.)

Comment: Btw, to have the exact same order for each coordinate as in the input (ordered by y-then-x instead of x-then-y), the `i++/n,i%n` should be `i++%n,i/n`. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Good point, updated the post!

Answer (score 7):

## Japt, 3 bytes

```
o ï
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=byDv&input=MwotUQ==)

```
o       :Range [0,input)
  ï     :Cartesian product with itself
```

Comment: I had the same solution with [` ñÌ`](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=byDvIPHM&input=MwoKLVI=) at the end to sort it. Hopefully the OP doesn't care about the order.

Comment: @Oliver, `mw` would also work.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>33</s> 25 bytes

```r
which(diag(scan())|1,T)-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMzlDIyUzMV2jODkxT0NTs8ZQJ0RT1/C/8X8A)

Thanks to [Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l) for suggesting a 2-byte golf, which inspired me to look further :-)

Comment: Where do you hear about all of these functions in R? I've never even used arrayInd before, but I feel like it could be useful in a lot of things!

Comment: @Sumner18 You can't be as golfy if you don't understand a big chunk of the language, so it pays to read the docs! there are a few workhorse functions like `match` and `which`. `which` in particular has an `arr.ind` argument, so looking at the documentation for `which`, we see a note in the Details under `.dimnames` about passing  to the `arrayInd` function!

Comment: [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/38@2ODkxT0PTujwjMzlDQ1HR0MpPNV8VSOqEaOoa/jf@DwA). Sadly, requires  `!!`, as otherwise: `argument to 'which' is not logical`...

Comment: @KirillL. that's neat! It also inspired me to shave off another 2 bytes. EDIT: another 6 bytes!

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
L<ãí',ý»
```

Exactly as the challenge description: prints the 0-indexed coordinates ordered by y-then-x comma- and newline-delimited to STDOUT.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx@bw4sNr1XUO7z20@/9/YwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
L          # Create a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
           #  i.e. 3 → [1,2,3]
 <         # Decrease each by 1 to make the range [0, input)
           #  i.e. [1,2,3] → [0,1,2]
  ã        # Create each possible pair with itself
           #  i.e. [0,1,2] → [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]]
   í       # Reverse each pair so they're sorted by y-then-x instead of x-then-y
           #  i.e. [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]]
           #   → [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[0,2],[1,2],[2,2]]
    ',ý   '# Join each pair with a space delimiter
           #  i.e. [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[0,2],[1,2],[2,2]]
           #   → ["0,0","1,0","2,0","0,1","1,1","2,1","0,2","1,2","2,2"]
       »   # And then join everything with a newline delimiter (and output implicitly)
           #  i.e. ["0,0","1,0","2,0","0,1","1,1","2,1","0,2","1,2","2,2"]
           #   → "0,0\n1,0\n2,0\n0,1\n1,1\n2,1\n0,2\n1,2\n2,2"
```

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Lã
```

Returns a list of 1-indexed coordinates ordered by x-then-y.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5/Di//@NAQ)

**Explanation:**

```python
L     # Create a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
      #  i.e. 3 → [1,2,3]
 ã    # Create each possible pair with itself (and output implicitly)
      #  i.e. [1,2,3] → [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]
```

Comment: How comes that your 2-byter is 1-indexed?

Comment: @maxb I've added an explanation to my post now. `L` is a 1-indexed list in the range `[1,n]` (where `n` is the implicit input). I've made it 0-indexed in my 8-byte answer with the `<` (decrease by 1).

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>48</s> 42 bytes

```powershell
param($n)0..--$n|%{$i=$_;0..$n|%{"$i,$_"}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVP00BPT1dXJa9GtVol01Yl3hrIB/OUVDJ1VOKVamv///9vDAA)

Boring double-for loop.

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to mazzy.*

Comment: ? `param($n)0..--$n|%{$i=$_;0..$n|%{"$i,$_"}}`

Comment: @mazzy Of course, removing the `-join`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## C#, <strike>59</strike>, 65

First time posting.  Apologies if I do something wrong!

`l=>{for(int j=0;j<l*l;)System.Console.Write($"{j%l},{j++/l}\n");}`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY2xCsIwGIT3PsVPUUisVsExbUGcBcHBxSXGtCT8TSSJgoQ8e2zF6Y77jjvhN8I6mQVy7@Hs7OD4GAuA5@uOSoAPPEzytuoBJ64MoTMEuHx8kGN9EEFZ0ygTOuihzdh2sbeOTAHodsd0gytk9N8@WuMtyvrqVJBkUUa9xLSOuqq2mG6mpCzleZz9Lnqyp7NLRcpf)  -per Kevin Crujissen's TIO Link.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unfortunately, assuming input is in a predefined variable is not a standard form of input. You could add a `console.readline()` or however that's supposed to work (I'm not too familiar with C#) or submit a function instead.

Comment: Hi, welcome to PPCG! We allow either functions or full programs as answers (yours is currently more like a snippet), and all imports add to the byte-count. Which means your current answer should be `l=>{for(var j=0;j<l*l;j++)System.Console.Write($"{j%l},{(int)j/l}\n");}` instead (71 bytes). However, you can golf 6 bytes by changing `(int)j/l` to `j++/l` and remove the `j++` like this: `l=>{for(int j=0;j<l*l;)System.Console.Write($"{j%l},{j++/l}\n");}`. [Try it online](https://tinyurl.com/ya3jc7tb).

Comment: Also, if you haven't seen it yet, [tips for golfing in C#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c) and [tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) might be interesting to read through. Apart from some ruling, your first answer looks fine, so +1 from me. Again welcome, and enjoy your stay! :)

Comment: Thanks guys!  Sorry about the function error.  Appreciate the for increment golf!

Comment: Can you provide a demo?

Comment: @sergiol Kevin provided a TIO link.  I put it on the post.

Answer (score 2):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 70 bytes

```
proc C {n i\ 0} {time {set j 0
time {puts $i,$j
incr j} $n
incr i} $n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYs7CoAwEAX7PcVDUloE9AZeI40Eiw1xDSaCEPbs8YfdzGNe8bG1tG8eE6qAHayiFl4X1LwUBFj6LB0lw3BvArH4HUFh5EN@UFtc5wRBpYFG0v8h7ry76Ynfoeu0XQ)

Comment: Failed outgolf: https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WcFZoTpPITNGwaBWobokMzdVobqgtKRYITq1oqBIQSVTXyUvVgfGUQVyrDPzkosUMmthKvK0gIK1/3NyEwsU8hSquYy5TLhqoYao5MVUqORxOQMZXGABJaXa/wA

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 39 bytes

```python
lambda n:[(i%n,i/n)for i in range(n*n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKlojUzVPJ1M/TzMtv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VSNPK08z9n9BUWZeiUKahrEmF5jJBRMw1fwPAA)

Comment: I think the question requires variable `N`...

Comment: @FelixPalmen Doh.. Fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 4 bytes

```
^UQ2
```

Full program. Outputs list of coordinate pairs.

```
^UQ2   Implicit: Q=eval(input())
 UQ    [0-Q)
^  2   Take the cartesian product of the previous result with itself
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 2 bytes

```
r■
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/7/o0bQF//8b/wcA)

### Explanation

```
r    Range(0, n)
 ■   Cartesian product with self for lists
```

For pretty-printing, you could add `n` to have it print one list item per line.

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 11 bytes

```
(⍳n)∘.,⍳n←⎕
```

Index origin = 0. Prompts for input for n and outputs the following for n=4:

```
0 0  0 1  0 2  0 3
1 0  1 1  1 2  1 3
2 0  2 1  2 2  2 3
3 0  3 1  3 2  3 3
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pepe](https://github.com/soaku/pepe), 88 bytes

I've never done 2D iterating in Pepe before and it doesn't seem to work pretty well due to labels being dynamic. There's quite a lot of two byte commands to avoid moving the pointer.

```
REREeErEErerErEReREErEEEErreEEreeeEeEEeerEEeerreEErEEEEEreeEReererEEEEErERRREEEEEeRrEree
```

[Try it online!](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/#&RE$__.F!q@MUw!k@M-iI/$-i_--&1-_*)

**Warning:** Do not run it with input below 1 - it will kill your browser.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-na`, 35 bytes

```perl
map{//;say"$',$_"for 0..$F[0]}0..$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saBaX9@6OLFSSUVdRyVeKS2/SMFAT0/FLdogthbEiP//3/hffkFJZn5e8X/dvMT/ur6megaGBgA)

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 43 bytes

```powershell
param($n)$i--..--$n*++$n|%{$i+=!$_;"$i,$_"}
```

Explanation:

One row `0..$n-1` repeated `$n` times.

Answer (score 1):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) (no external utilities), 35

```bash
eval echo {0..$[$1-1]},{0..$[$1-1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhfnFqioKurYPw/tSwxRyE1OSNfodpAT08lWsVQ1zC2VgeZ8/8/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 63 bytes

```lua
s=io.read()-1 for i=0,s do for j=0,s do print(i..','..j)end end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/2DYzX68oNTFFQzPL1kAhLb9IIdPWQKdY11AhJR/MBQrrGIE4BUWZeSUamXp66jrqenpZmql5KQpA/P@/MQA)

Answer (score 0):

## Perl5, <s>42</s> 38 bytes

```
for$i(0..--$n){for(0..$n){say"$i,$_"}}
```

(The inner loop saves a few bytes by using the implicit variable "$_" as an index.)