# !I!n!s!e!r!t! !i!n!b!e!t!w!e!e!n!

Tags: code-golf, string

Posted from [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/17916#17916).

This challenge is highly "distilled" from [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188863/print-function-for-linked-list) question. Special thanks to @Akababa!

In this task, you should insert an exclamation mark at the start of the string and after every character.

### Rules

- There will always be a non-empty-string input. The input will not contain tabs either. You can assume that the input only contain non-extended ASCII printable characters and newlines.
- The input will not contain trailing newlines as long as your language can't detect a newline.
- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) contest; the shortest answer should win.

### Examples

- 4 newlines result in 5 newline-delimited exclamation marks. It is very hard to put this as a Markdown text, so this is stated instead.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
129591 129012 129127 129582

0
```

Outputs

```
!1! !2! !3! !4! !5! !6!
!1!2!9!5!9!1! !1!2!9!0!1!2! !1!2!9!1!2!7! !1!2!9!5!8!2!
!
!0!
```

```
asd afjoK ak:e
kPrLd
    fOJOE;
    KFO
KFkepjgop sgpaoj   faj
```

Outputs

```
!a!s!d! !a!f!j!o!K! !a!k!:!e!
!k!P!r!L!d!
! ! ! ! !f!O!J!O!E!;!
! ! ! ! !K!F!O!
!K!F!k!e!p!j!g!o!p! !s!g!p!a!o!j! ! ! !f!a!j!
```

A base test case with only one character:

```
a
```

Outputs

```
!a!
```

(Auto-completion! Just kidding, there is no such thing.) Contains exclamation marks:

```
!!
!!
!!
!!
!!
```

Outputs:

```
!!!!!
!!!!!
!!!!!
!!!!!
!!!!!
```

Comment: [very similar question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75979/full-width-text?r=SearchResults)

Comment: I didn't encounter this in the Sandbox though. (Also, that question takes one line of input.)

Comment: Downvoting without stating the reason is not a good idea. "The purpose of the policy is that I shouldn't be able to reuse the same answer to multiple questions."

Comment: I really don't understand the downvote - this is a clear and well written challenge. Re: being a duplicate - it's not (preceding '!' makes for a big difference), and I don't believe anyone has suggested so (no close votes).

Comment: if a language can't tell the difference between `a\n` and `a`, can we require that there are no trailing newlines?

Comment: I think so, as long as your statement is true.

Comment: Downvotes are inserted between every upvote, just like what the challege describes.

Comment: Is the case of a single space input `" "`, is the output supposed to be "!" or "! !"

Comment: @Kai The output is supposed to be ```! !```.

Comment: Is the input supposed to be only a string or could it be an array of characters?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel generally, they're [considered equivalent](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2216/81203)

Comment: This has 42 votes. Is this the meaning of life?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 1 byte

Thanks to A__ for halving the byte count!

```apl
!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6/1/x/39DBSMFYwUTBVMFMy5DI0tTS0MFIGVgaASiDI3MQZSphREXlwEA)

Replaces nothing with `!`

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 26 bytes

```python
lambda s:s.replace('','!')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BT8MwDIXv/hVuLm3RQE1GgRXtyCQoUrkDB486Y@1IoiQS4teXprvMsvQ9PT0/2f3Fb2vWk95@TCf62feEoQk3nt2JvrjI81We5eUUOcSAW3wXzyawj7jn@MtsxAqEEBIVrvEWa7wDqTb1RuKMSqoEqe4T6gcFUM3h5YJCj6QH2yKNDcP45l97wHl099I9PS6y3XXQ7kZ2w8E6DAdHdkgJGs4tdK7KMrjY2YBPANDWY3oaj2ZhaJZO548mFuJaXKmqvHB0kUJlOf0D)

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 13):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 2 bytes

```
!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fS/H/f0MFIwVjBRMFUwUzLkMjS1NLQwUgZWBoBKIMjcxBlKmFEReXAQA) At last, a challenge where Retina has a built-in!

Comment: Actually, I created this challenge based on this Retina built-in.

Comment: [Works in QuadR too.](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6/59L8f9/QwUjBWMFEwVTBTMuQyNLU0tDBSBlYGgEogyNzEGUqYURF5cBAA "QuadR – Try It Online")

Comment: [-1](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6/1/x/39DBSMFYwUTBVMFMy5DI0tTS0MFIGVgaASiDI3MQZSphREXlwEA) bytes in QuadR.

Comment: @A__ Right, I forgot about [that feature](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS#code) (*If there is only one non-function line…*). You may want to [re-consider your check-mark](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190258/43319).

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 27 bytes

```python
lambda s:f"!{'!'.join(s)}!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BTsMwEETv@xXrvTRBgGK3AZqqRypBkNJ74eAqdolDbSu2hBDi20OcXrpa6Y1Gs6P1P/HT2eWot@/jlzwfW4mh0sR@F2xxb1xns5D/MRqjCjHgFg/0YoMaIh5V/FbK0i0QEUeBS1xhiQ/Axbpcc5xQcJHAxWNC@SQAiik8X8jQotTG1Sj7SkG/H95awGl089o8b2ZZ7xqod73y5uQ8hpOXzqSENJcWealiDK52MuADALQbMD2NnZ0ZqrnTD52NGd3RjSjyK0dnKZTn4z8)

Honestly, I hope someone can show me a cool way to do this with a smaller byte count.

Comment: This doesnt handle the empty line case correctly

Comment: @flakes What do you mean? If you mean an empty string: we do not need to handle an empty string (and regardless this outputs `!!` in that case, which is what makes sense to me). If you mean the string `\n`: it does, since the correct output is `!\n!`.

Comment: @JAD As far as I can see, it doesn't have an empty string in the examples. Not only that, but the first rule literally states "there will always be a non-empty string input."

Comment: Ah I was incorrect. The first example has an empty line in the middle of the input. But this answer will handle placing the exclamation point in the middle of that, `!\n!\n!`. nice work.

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/190223/insert-nbetween/190386#190386 as you were saying to show a shorter way

Answer (score 12):

## Haskell, 18 bytes

```
('!':).(>>=(:"!"))
```

-1 byte thanks to @nimi

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzX0NdUd1KU0/Dzs5Ww0pJUUlT839uYmaegq1CemqJc35eSWpeSbECUFahoLQkuKTIJ09BTyHtf1p@vkJSYhEQV3FlAM3K/5eclpOYXvxfN8I5IAAA)

Comment: `('!':).` saves a byte.

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 27 bytes

```python
lambda s:'!%s!'%'!'.join(s)
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYwxEoIwEAD7e0VSMAeNhSUOpRTGmfgAmnNCkESSG47G18foVlvsLH@OV07n4oepvGl7OlLSo25EY4MaTyGvqZWuyICIE5A4RT5koyj2M8THfnegKt7e7PXyVzNaMGOcOSyZlSxMOfwKCnUBwPuajtbXaVe@)**

Answer (score 11):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>24</s> 22 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to JoKing.

```
-[-[-<]>>+<],[>.<.,]>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fNxoIbWLt7LRtYnWi7fRs9HRi7fT@//dUyMkvS1VwgqkEAA)

Comment: damn, that's badass

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), 19 bytes

Takes input as an array of characters.

```javascript
s=>`!${s.join`!`}!`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hYxNC4JAFEX371e8gUAlGpwpKwvb5SID21cwg184iiNOtIl@u2mrFoGXC@cuDlfJpzRJV7aPRaPTrM@D3gQHQWYvQ5UuG0HEm4g@0Y3RdUZrXdi5faWUCoYcl7hCD9fAuO/5DAe4jI9gfDPC23IAV9wdnKN1aywH4M@TNCnKXOkIZbXLoLp05xRwSB6f4uP@O6MwhiisslYVukVTtFKr0ZBq8n1KIAR@OthO/wE)

---

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>23</s>  20 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @ShieruAsakoto*

Takes input as a string.

```javascript
s=>[,...s,,].join`!`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYzBCoJAGITv/1P8nlSyxd2ysrBbHjKwewW76Cqu4oobvf6mnaJDw8A3MMMo8RKmGJvhuex1KW2VWJMcbwEhxATBgyjd9NzhttC90Z0kna69yuMUGa5wjRFugLI4iilOCCmbQdl2RrRjACH3cYHuvXd9gJ8TYUoUldIZinYvob2OlxJwUpWf89PhE7M0hyxt5aBqPaCpB6HVvBDq3/GfznHgy9z37Rs)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 22 bytes

*Suggested by [@tjjfvi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/87606/tjjfvi)*

Takes input as a string.

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/|/g,"!")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYyxDoIwGIT3/yl@WKBRgVZR0eAmg5jgAzjQQCEWQhtqnHx3BCfjwOWS75K7nOQvbor@oZ@rTpViqOLBxCfj9UK3vBCu//brpW3ZZChUZ1QrvFbVbuXmFBmucYMhboGyKIwojggom0DZbkK4ZwBBTnCBzr1zCMDfCTcl8kqqFHlzENDc@msJOKrKLtn5@I1pkkGaNELLWmk0teZKTgsu545nOsuCH@eEDB8)

Comment: [Alternative with `.replace`, 22 bytes](https://tio.run/##fYyxDoIwGIT3/yl@WKBRgVZR0eAmg5jgAzjQQCEWQhtqnHx3BCfjwOWS75K7nOQvbor@oZ@rTpViqOLBxCfj9UK3vBCu//brpW3ZZChUZ1QrvFbVbuXmFBmucYMhboGyKIwojggom0DZbkK4ZwBBTnCBzr1zCMDfCTcl8kqqFHlzENDc@msJOKrKLtn5@I1pkkGaNELLWmk0teZKTgsu545nOsuCH@eEDB8 "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: @tjjfvi Nifty one!

Comment: I've got a 20 for your 23: ``s=>[,...s,,].join`!` ``

Answer (score 9):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth),  <s>19 11 10</s>  9 bytes

```
33
..
",@
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/f2JhLT49LScfh///g/JyyVK6QjFQuH5i8IgA)**

#### How?

We enter the Labyrinth at the top-left facing right with an infinite stack of zeros...

```
                         I / O    stack
                                  0,0,0,...
3 - pop * 10 + 3                  3,0,0,0,...
  - 2 neighbours, forward
3 - pop * 10 + 3                  33,0,0,0,...
  - 2 neighbours, forward
. - pop & print chr          !    0,0,0,...
  - T junction from the side
  -   TOS==0, forward
, - read chr or -1       L        76,0,0,0,...   or   -1,0,0,0
  - T junction from the base
  -   if TOS > 0 right:
" -     no-op                     76,0,0,0,...
  -     2 neighbours, forward
. -     pop & print chr      L    0,0,0,...
  -     T junction from the side
  -       TOS==0, forward
3 -       ...back to the start
  -   elif TOS == -1 left:
@ -     exit                                          we're out!


  * right, but on the first occasion (from above) we hit the wall and turn
    around, so that's like a left
```

Luckily we don't need to handle un-printables, otherwise the first zero-byte would turn us around at `,` and play havoc.

Answer (score 7):

## [Pepe](https://github.com/Soaku/Pepe), 47 bytes

```
REREEeRErEErREeeEeeeeEREEeeREEeereeREEEEeeEReee
```

[Try it online!](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/#&T&E@!8j!l!l*DvH)

**Explanation:**

```c
REREEeRE # Push 0,then input (str),then 0 -> (R)
         # The zeroes are pushed to correct the inserting
rEE # Begin loop labelled 0 -> (r)
  rREeeEeeeeE # Push "!" -> (R)
              # r flag inserts it instead of pushing
  REEeeREEee # Move pointer pos 2 steps forward -> (R)
ree # Loop while (R) != 0
REEEEeeE # Remove characters of (R) that are in stack of (r)
         # Removes the 0 in (R)
Reee # Output (R)
```

Comment: How do you write this code? Is there some code converter that you use? This seems crazy to try and write

Comment: @Cruncher 1) I use [this](https://github.com/Soaku/Pepe/blob/master/commands.md) as my guide. 2) Nope, I don't use a code converter, I just use the guide to write the code.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 25 bytes

```r
function(x)gsub("","!",x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQjO9uDRJQ0lJR0lRSadC83@ahpJHak5OvkJ5flFOiqKS5n8A)

A function accepting and returning a character vector.

Comment: Can shave 3 bytes by switching the function form to `scan(,'')`, like so https://tio.run/##K/r/P724NElDSUlHSVFJpzg5MU9DR11dU/O/kkdqTk6@Qnl@UU6KotJ/AA

Comment: @Sumner18 thanks. I started with that but it splits input at spaces.

Comment: @Sumner18 The challenge asks to handle input with newlines, which can't be done with `scan` (but which Nick's solution does handle, at least if you display the output with `cat`.)

Answer (score 7):

## 8086 machine code, .COM format (MS-DOS 2+), 32 bytes

(-1 depending on emulator: see below)

For best results redirect standard input from a file, as typing gives odd-looking output due to no buffering; also, newlines look a little weird because they are stored as `CR LF`, and the `CR` part messes up the output.

This program behaves fine in an actual MS-DOS emulation (e.g. PCjs) but DOSBox seemed to have issues with Ctrl+Z EOF (see comments in the assembly listing), so *DON'T* try to enter input using the console in DOSBox unless you add the extra check!

```
BB 01 00 53 59 BA 0B 01 B4 40 CD 21 4A 4B B4 3F CD 21 85 C0 74 09 B4 40 43 41 CD 21 49 EB EE C3
```

Some interesting bits:

- I saved some data space by reusing memory that had already been executed (the `21H` in `INT 21H` happens to be `!`)
- I was *almost* able to use an interesting trick that I found on the page ["The Hidden Power of BCD Instructions"](http://www.hugi.scene.org/online/coding/hugi%2017%20-%20coaax.htm) which would have allowed me to use `AAA` instead of a standard `TEST` to compare `AL` to 0, saving one byte. Unfortunately, this is not fully documented so I couldn't rely on it: for example, PCjs doesn't adjust anything but the carry and auxiliary carry flags. :-(

Assembly code (TASM ideal mode):

```
IDEAL
MODEL   TINY

CODESEG
ORG 100H

;; DOSBox (tested with 0.74-2) didn't seem to handle Ctrl-Z as EOF
;; so uncomment the ";;" lines to run it there.
MAIN:
    MOV     BX,1
    PUSH    BX
    POP     CX
    MOV     DX,OFFSET MAIN_1+1  ; The 21H in INT 21H
    MOV     AH,40H
MAIN_1:
    INT     21H
    DEC     DX
    ;;PUSH  DX
    ;;POP   SI
IO_LOOP:
    DEC     BX
    MOV     AH,3FH
    INT     21H
    ;;; This should work on an non-emulated PC. 
    ;;;AAA      ; AL=0?
    TEST    AX,AX
    JZ      DONE
    ;;CMP   [BYTE PTR SI],1AH
    ;;JZ    DONE
    MOV     AH,40H
    INC     BX
    INC     CX
    INT     21H
    DEC     CX
    JMP     IO_LOOP
DONE:
    RET
ENDS
END MAIN
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ż”!ṁż
```

A full program accepting a string, which prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o7kcNcxUf7mw8uuf////q6uqJxSkKiWlZ@d4KidlWqVzZAUU@KVwKQJDm7@Xvag1merv5c3m7ZacWZKXnFygUpxck5meBVCRmAQ0AAA)**

#### How?

```
Ż”!ṁż - Main Link: list of characters, s   e.g. "abc"
 ”!   - character '!'                           '!'
   ṁ  - mould like:
Ż     -   s with a zero prepended              "!!!!"
    ż - zip together with s                    ["!a","!b","!c",'!']
      - implicit (smashing) print              !a!b!c!
```

Answer (score 5):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 12 bytes

```
s/\b\|\B/!/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1g/JimmJsZJX1E//f9/QwUjBWMFEwVTBTMuQyNLU0tDBSBlYGgEogyNzEGUqYURF5cBAA)

*-3 bytes thanks to Cows Quack*

Comment: Actually the Sed code is just 15 characters there: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1hfT19NUT/dulg/Tl9R//9/QwUjBWMFEwVTBTMuQyNLU0tDBSBlYGgEogyNzEGUqYURF5cBAA "sed – Try It Online").

Comment: Great, thank you.  I was unclear how that worked...

Comment: `s/\b\|\B/!/g` also works for 12 bytes

Comment: @Cowsquack thank you.  updated.

Answer (score 5):

## 6502, 12 bytes (13 bytes if Apple II)

**6502**

The machine code assumes that a pair of zero page locations are connected to character input ($FE) and output (FF) hardware. Many 6502-based systems facilitate I/O in this fashion, albeit I/O address are usually not in zero page.

For simplicity, I used [Py65](https://github.com/mnaberez/py65), a 6502 microcomputer system simulator written in Python.

Here is a memory dump from Py65. You can load the following code anywhere in zero page such that it does not overlap $FE and $FF.

```
       PC  AC XR YR SP NV-BDIZC
6502: 0000 00 00 00 ff 00110010
.mem 0:b
0000:  a9  21  85  ff  a5  fe  f0  fc  85  ff  d0  f4
```

Running in a Windows command window, you can paste (Ctrl+V) any text you desire, or you can simply type. If typing, press Ctrl+J for a newline (same ASCII char). Press Ctrl+C to interrupt the processor and return to the Py65 command prompt.

Naturally, assembly code is easier to read.

```
       PC  AC XR YR SP NV-BDIZC
6502: 0000 00 00 00 ff 00110010
.d 00:0b
$0000  a9 21     LDA #$21
$0002  85 ff     STA $ff
$0004  a5 fe     LDA $fe
$0006  f0 fc     BEQ $0004
$0008  85 ff     STA $ff
$000a  d0 f4     BNE $0000
```

For clarity, here is the assembly code in [CBA65](http://www.crbond.com/tools.htm) format.

```
; ASSEMBLE:
; cba65 bangit
;
; LOAD/RUN
; python3 py65/monitor.py -i 00fe -o 00ff -l bangit.bin
; goto 0000

        .FILES  BIN=256

; I/O LOCATIONS
GETC    .EQU    $FE             ; (1) MOVING PY65'S GETC TO ZP SHAVES 1 BYTE
PUTC    .EQU    $FF             ; (1) MOVING PY65'S PUTC TO ZP SHAVES 2 BYTES

        .ORG    $0000

VROOM   LDA     #'!'
        STA     PUTC
VROOM2  LDA     GETC
        BEQ     VROOM2
        STA     PUTC
        BNE     VROOM

        .END
```

**Apple II**

The code above assumes a null indicates there is no input, so continues polling until a non-null value is returned.

For comparison, the Apple I and Apple II signals availability of a new character by setting bit 7 of the keyboard I/O address, which then needs to be cleared after fetching the character. On those systems, character I/O usually is performed by calling system monitor routines instead of accessing the hardware directly.

By calling RDKEY ($FD0C) and COUT ($FDED), the Apple II equivalent of the above can be coded in 13 bytes, and is runnable anywhere in RAM. Here is the code I ran in an Apple //e emulator, [a2ix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.deadc0de.apple2ix.basic&hl=en_US) on Android 9.

Pressing Return has the same effect as a newline.

```
*300L

0300-   A9 A1       LDA   #$A1
0302-   20 ED FD    JSR   $FDED
0305-   20 0C FD    JSR   $FD0C
0308-   20 ED FD    JSR   $FDED
030B-   F0 F3       BEQ   $0300
```

Did you notice that instead of the normal ASCII value #$21 for the exclamation point, #$A1 is used instead? That's because sending standard ASCII values to COUT causes them to be displayed in "inverse mode," black on white. Displaying ASCII in normal white on black requires adding #$80 to the character value in the accumulator before calling COUT. Because RDKEY returns characters with the hi-bit set, assembly programs generally cleared the bit of the character to obtain its ASCII value before using it.

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Comment: Thank you, @Rahul!

Answer (score 4):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>32</s> 23 bytes

```sh
<<<!${(j:!:)${(s::)1}}!
```

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYvLCoJAGIX3/1McSVAXQTNlF6OlLTKwB2gz6ExeYkYcISh69klr08eB7yzOedrKPar6LhGG8GeIoj1K45TpUSAMAviv0CZJxN6RLCqDuU7hF56zVa0G6vpaDwrBVR9@XHVApdHSOQaOJVaIsSbGd/GOYdSC8UmMbybFW060ICdsCaEak0G0iaT20p9LwojKT3m6/9bsmFN2bGXX3EwHe@uEaaaFaMa/8zz6ywc)</s>

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYvLDoIwFET39ytuIwmwo1VUCi5lISb4AW6alFcxtKEkJhq@vYJuPJnkzGLmZVv3bLtHhUGA3gbDMEWpXZZlxHsHihMeLrach3SeibNtV09gxm6YavTvw@nHffBB6qFyjiLDLe4wxj1QlsQJxUURZasoO6yKjwwgAiesRFErXaDoeQX9bbxKwIW6vJTn9FuLvIQi7yujGm3QNkZotS6EWv6OEPjLBw)

`(s::)` splits into characters, `(j:!:)` joins on `!`s.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) -p0, <s>17</s> 6 bytes

```perl
s,,!,g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxBDsIgFEXROat4rY0jbOAr1Zq4FtMBaTENkA9Ndy9SRyd3cqPl1ZRTYDc7P62YfNotY3d5wWdLGZf4j7BlKDhfW2GxbJ/o3q@2afske9mdGzlzSVJWS9EgXHGDwSA0jWbUqChNB5ruB@ZBQqhviNkFn0rd/gA)

My original answer was `-p` and `$_='!'.s,.,$&!,gr`. Thanks to @Nahuel Fouilleul for cutting 11 bytes and to @Grimy for the `-p0` tip.

Comment: [6 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YR0dRJ/3/f0MFIwVjBRMFUwUzLkMjS1NLQwUgZWBoBKIMjcxBlKmFEReXwb/8gpLM/Lzi/7o5BQA)

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul `-lp` gives incorrect output for the `\n\n\n\n` test case (returns 4 newline-separated `!` instead of the specified 5). `-p0` works correctly.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>16</s> 11 bytes

```perl6
{S:g/<(/!/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OtgqXd9GQ19Rv/Z/cWKlQppCcU5pUcF/QwUjBWMFEwVTBTMuQyNLU0tDBSBlYGgEogyNzEGUqYURF5cBAA)

Replaces all zero width matches with exclamation marks. Null regexes are not allowed, so we use a capture marker to capture nothing instead

Answer (score 4):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 7 bytes

```
'!,#@~,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9XV9RRdqjT@f/fUMFIwVjBRMFUwYzL0MjS1NJQAUgZGBqBKEMjcxBlamHExWUAAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [MarioLANG](https://github.com/tomsmeding/MarioLANG), <s>95</s> <s>94</s> <s>90</s> <s>89</s> 69 bytes

```
++++++
======< >)
>+++++++",+[
=======<.==<
>+++++++!(.-
========#===
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syszPScxL//9fGwy4bMHARsFOk8sOIqStpKMdDRW3tdEDYriMooaeLkzGVhmI//9PLE5RSEzLyvdWSMy2SuXKDijySeFSAII0fy9/V2sw09vNn8vbLTu1ICs9v0ChOL0gMT8LpCIxCwA)

First time trying out MarioLANG, that was a lot of fun!

*Thanks to **Jo King** for -20 bytes*

**Explanation:**

So, as the name implies, MarioLANG is made to execute like a game of Super Mario Bros. It operates similarly to BF, with memory arranged in a tape of cells. There are operators to increment, decrement, print (as ascii or numeric) and read into the current memory cell, and operators to move left or right along the tape.

Mario (the instruction pointer) always begins in the top left cell of the program, with his intended direction of motion set to the right. If Mario does not have a floor-like object beneath him (=, ", or #), he will fall until he reaches a floor-like object. If Mario leaves the program space, the program ends due to Game Over :(

This specific program can basically be split into two halves: the setup, and the loop.

```
   Setup                          Loop
-----------------------------------------------
                       |
++++++                 |          
======<                |          >)
>+++++++               |          ",+[
=======<               |          .==<
>+++++++               |          !(.-
========               |          #===
```

In the Setup section, we're simply incrementing the first memory cell until we reach 33 - the ASCII value for "!". Easy enough; if this can be golfed, it's purely a matter of shape. Mario starts from the top left, picks up 10 coins, starts falling when picking up the 11th, switches directions, then repeats. He picks up the last 11 coins without switching directions; he ends the setup section at the bottom-rightmost "+".

In the loop section, Mario starts by reaching an elevator. The "!" operator makes him cease motion, so that he remains on the elevator. On the way up, it prints the corresponding ASCII character to the current memory cell's value (this one is always 33, "!"), then switches to the next cell in memory. Mario reaches the top and sets his direction to the right. He falls, and reads a character from input as its ASCII value (or -1 if no character). We increment because the only measure of control in MarioLANG is to skip an instruction if the current memory cell has a value of 0. If it does, we skip changing Mario's direction, so he will walk right off of the next floor to his doom. If it does not, we set direction to left; walking left off of the floor below decrements the current cell back to its previous value, that value is printed, and we move back to the first memory cell before getting back on the elevator.

---

**Previous version (89 bytes):**

```
+++++++++++>,
==========@"+
+++++++++++)[
@==========.==<
+++++++++++!(.-
===========#===
```

Comment: [62 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syszPScxL//9fGwi4bEFAU8FOj8sOxNfWUNLQ0eZSAgtHawIxlyJQVFPXRlFP14ZLGSxuC6L@/08sTlFITMvK91ZIzLZK5coOKPJJ4VIAgjR/L39XazDT282fy9stO7UgKz2/QKE4vSAxPwukIjELAA) by using a multiplication loop instead of just a counter

Comment: Okay now THAT is cool. I'll update as soon as I have time to redo the explanation, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Aha! [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYqxDoMwEEP3@4qDLqArfAANbGVoKqU700lA1ARIBP@v9FJLtuwn73x@w8aHTYmAiGqCXqRwaGGQTVVZ3QnKDKdaDIWcGlW0jYJbpn3OlPiakVcXNLLvFvCf8z0DilbzMs/Hv@rRgB79Ep0NES8bObj8YPcD) by multiplying 5*6 + 3 instead of 8*4+1

Comment: Man, I know it isn't exactly your first rodeo, but this is really impressive. xD

Comment: Actually, this is my first time golfing MarioLANG. I just have some experience with brainfuck as well as other 2D languages

Answer (score 4):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 11 bytes

```
gsub(a,"!")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v8/vbg0SSNRR0lRSfP//8TiFIXEtKx8b4XEbKtUruyAIp8ULgUgSPP38ne1BjO93fy5vN2yUwuy0vMLFIrTCxLzs0AqErMA)

This is similar to some other entries.  It changes a null string to `!` globally, using `$0` as the default target, then prints the result since no other action is defined.  Using `a` works since it's an undefined variable and is shorter than using `""` (which would do the same thing).

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 bytes

```apl
(∊⊢⍪⍪¨)∘'!'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wSNRx1dj7oWPepdBUSHVmg@6pihrqgOlFM3VDBSMFYwUTBVBwA)

@Adám's golf to mine (see below).

```apl
{'!'⍪∊⍉↑⍵('!'⍴⍨≢⍵)}  ⍝ original
{'!'⍪∊⍵⍪¨('!'⍴⍨≢⍵)}  ⍝ concatenate each instead of transpose mix
{'!'⍪∊⍵⍪¨ '!'}       ⍝ each already handles many-to-one
{ ⍵ ⍪∊⍺⍪¨  ⍵ }∘'!'   ⍝ break out "!"
{∊⍵ ⍪ ⍺⍪¨  ⍵ }∘'!'   ⍝ defer flattening to later
(∊⊢ ⍪  ⍪¨    )∘'!'   ⍝ go tacit
(∊⊢⍪⍪¨)∘'!'          ⍝ remove spacing
```

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 19 bytes

```apl
{'!'⍪∊⍉↑⍵('!'⍴⍨≢⍵)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqdUX1R72rHnV0PertfNQ28VHvVg2w0JZHvSsedS4C8jVrgUoV1A0VjBSMFUwUTBXM1AE)

My first APL submission :P Loving this language. No idea why I need the parentheses after `⍵`.

```apl
{'!'⍪∊⍉↑⍵('!'⍴⍨≢⍵)}
{                   } ⍝ Boilerplate
              ⍴⍨      ⍝ Repeat
           '!'        ⍝ Exclamation point
                 ≢⍵  ⍝ len(input) times
         ⍵(        )  ⍝ Wrap ^ into an array with the input
       ↑              ⍝ Matrixify
      ⍉               ⍝ Transpose
     ∊                ⍝ Flatten
    ⍪                  ⍝ Prepend
 '!'                  ⍝ An exclamation point
```

Comment: Congrats on your first APL answer! I'm quite impressed, considering how new you are to APL. With experience, you will be able to golf this to `'!'∘(∊,¨,⊣)`

Comment: @Adám thanks! This is just the culmination of a few hours practice, I was sure it could be golfed :D

Comment: @Adám what does that exactly do? seems like a bunch of compositions?

Comment: [Let's continue this discussion in chat…](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard "The APL Orchard")

Comment: @Hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian : that code I counted 19 `UTF-8` characters, but 37 bytes. Please illustrate exactly where your 19 bytes came from. If you whatever-unicode code page could map 19 `UTF-8` code points to just 19 bytes, i wanna see the mapping of it. Don't try selling me transparent silk.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto based on the [Dyalog APL codepage](http://help.dyalog.com/15.0/Content/Language/System%20Functions/av.htm#kanchor1235) the bytes would be `185 173 59 208 208 128 248 184 13 204 13` (thi is for the shorter of the 2 answers).

Comment: I've locked the comments under this answer for a day, as this has gone beyond both polite discussion and the intended use of comments. Please think carefully about if your comment actually improves the answer before posting, once the lock is lifted

Answer (score 3):

## [Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular), <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
B\3;#*~.,</@<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/3ynG2FpZq05Px0bfweb//8TiFIXEtKx8b4XEbKtUruyAIp8ULgUgSPP38ne1BjO93fy5vN2yUwuy0vMLFIrTCxLzs0AqErMA)

*-2 bytes after remembering that Triangular has a conditional halt operator.*

I believe this is as short as it gets on this one. Triangular *does* have conditional direction-change operators, but they unfortunately work differently than the other conditionals. While all others check if ToS <= 0, the direction-changing conditionals check ToS != 0. If this weren't the case, we would have 10 bytes in the form of `Bq3~#*/@<<`.

Ungolfed:

```
    B
   \ 3
  ; # *
 ~ . , <
/ @ <
----------------------------------------------------
B3*              - Push 11 and 3, then pop both and push their product.
    <,<          - Change directions 3 times (to save 2 bytes on last line)
        @/       - Print Top of Stack value as a character, do not pop
          ~;\    - Push a character from input to ToS. Halt if ToS <= 0. Change Direction.
              #  - Print ToS as a character and pop
```

---

**Previous Version (15 bytes):**

```
B.3\.*#).(/?~@<
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 28 bytes

```cs
s=>$"!{String.Join("!",s)}!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpds4@maV5qbWpSYlJNqk5yRWGSno4AhZJdm@7/Y1k5FSbE6uKQoMy9dzys/M09DSVFJp1izVlHpvzVXeFFmSapPZl6qRpqGUmZecWpRiUJSakl5amqekqam9X8A)

Comment: nice use of interpolated strings, wouldn't have thought of that

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 20 bytes

A lambda function from `String` to `String`.

```java
s->s.replace("","!")
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##PU/LasMwEDwrX7ERBCxwRN@HtPGxt55yLKVsFTnIlR941ymh@NtdyXIDgpFGszOzFZ5xWx2/p2748s6A8UgEb@ga@F2JhSRGDnBu3RHq8JUduHfN6f0DsD@RikpRBSM9sPO6HBrDrm3063J5SfIcEhZQwn6ibUG6t51HYzMpc7mWahLiOVhd3Q2SJdhDY3/gSsYwIW/hDu7hAR7hSeYzs8DNgmyJQ/E4NDNjdC7bHpbys/kn7FJI2kEcLsS21u3Augsi9v@r6jBZI2dyE/oUsCGZJ4McSo1d5y/Z/FRKxZxxFc44/QE)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
€'!Ć
```

I/O as a list of characters.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UdMadcUjbf//RyslKukoKBWDiBQQoQAiwGJpICILROSDCG9U2WwQYQUiUkFETB5cMABEFIEIH7ipEGkFLATYFn8Q4QVnuYIIa/z6wM5xg2uBKEQIZsNdVgD3RjrcLwVwY4rhEgVwr@XDdWBzayJENhYA)

**Explanation:**

```python
€'!  '# Prepend a "!"-item before each character in the (implicit) input-list
   Ć  # Enclose (append the first character of the list at the end of it)
      # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>11</s> 6 bytes

```
"!"oio
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X0lRKT8z//9/QwUjBWMFEwVTBTMA)

Saved 5 bytes thanks to Jo King, suggesting exiting with an error. Previous version which does not exit with an error:

```
"!"oi:0(?;o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X0lRKT/TykDD3jr//39DBSMFYwUTBVMFMwA)

Comment: You can remove the `:0(?;` to terminate in an error

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.gsub'',?!}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664ulgvvbg0SV1dx16x9n9BaUmxQlq0kmdecWpRiUJSakl5amqeUiwXVMLGpqKiIpbLUMFIwVjBRMFUwYzL0MjS1NJQAUgZGBqBKEMjcxBlamHExWXABVT/HwA)

Thanks Value Ink for -1 byte

Comment: Remove the space after `gsub`.

Answer (score 3):

## [SimpleTemplate](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate), 23 bytes

This is a language I wrote, and it was supposed to be for templates, but well.

```
!{@eachargv.0}{@echo_}!
```

Should be almost self-explanatory, once you see the ungolfed code:

```
!{@each argv.0 as char} {@echo char}!{@/}
```

And an explanation:

- `!` - Prints the literal `!` character
- `{@each argv.0 as char}` - Loops through every character, with the value set to the variable `char` (**optional**, the default variable is `_`).
  `argv.0` is the first parameter passed to the `render()` method of the compiler.
- `{@echo char}!` - outputs the `char` variable and a literal `!` character.
  For the golfed version, the default variable `_` is used instead.
- `{@/}` - closes the loop (**optional**)

---

Pure **SimpleTemplate** solution:

```
{@fn x}!{@eachargv.0}{@echo_}!{@/}{@/}
```

Creates a function `x` that outputs the same result.

You can use it like this:

```
{@call x "this is an example"}
```

You can try all of this on: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f6baff8d411fc8227ece81eccf05b6e7d3586bfa

On the line 908, you can use the variables `$golfed`, `$ungolfed` and `$fn` to test all the versions.

---

---

However, if it is allowed to use a character array, the code is simplified (20 bytes):

```
!{@echoj"!" argv.0}!
```

And ungolfed:

```
!{@echo separator "!" argv.0}!
```

Basically, outputs all items in the array, joined by `"!"`, surrounded by literal `!`.
Due to limitations in the compiler class, the space is mandatory (in the golfed version).

This code is also extremelly harder to use in pure **SimpleTemplate** (using the function as example):

```
{@fn x}!{@echoj"!" argv.0}!{@/}

{@// alternative: @call str_split into a "a char array"}
{@set a "a", " ", "c", "h", "a", "r", " ", "a", "r", "r", "a", "y"}

{@call x a}
```

The `@call` can call a function that exists in PHP, which means that it isn't a pure **SimpleTemplate** solution.

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 36 bytes

```bash
while read -n1 c;do printf \!$c;done
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzwjMydVoSg1MUVBN89QIdk6JV@hoCgzryRNIUZRBcTNS/3/PyQjs1gBiBIVSlKLSxQy8wpKS/S4AA)

This counts on the newline terminating the input for the last ! mark.

Comment: Welcome! Please consider adding an explanation or link to an interpreter or something, because code-only answers are automatically flagged as low-quality.

Comment: @mbomb007, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not add an `!` at the end of the input.

Comment: @Cowsquack: on my terminal, the newline that terminates the input gets the ! added. On tio.run, the input needs to be terminated with a carriage return. I've updated the link to the Try it Online to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

## VBA, <s>75 bytes</s> 72 bytes

72 bytes as a sub that outputs to the immediate window (thanks @taylorscott)

```vb
Sub s(x):Debug.?"!";:For i=1To Len(x):Debug.?Mid(x,i,1)"!";:Next:End Sub
```

75 bytes as a function that returns the formatted string.

```vb
Function t(x):t="!":For i=1To Len(x):t=t &Mid(x,i,1) &"!":Next:End Function
```

Which expands to and is readable as

```vb
Public Function t(x)
    t = "!"
    For i = 1 To Len(x)
        t = t & Mid(x, i, 1) & "!"
    Next
End Function
```

Test cases

```vb
Public Sub test_golf()

    x = "1 2 3 4 5 6" & vbCr & "129591 129012 129127 129582" & vbCr & vbCr & "0"
    'x = "a"
    'x = "!!" & vbCr & "!!" & vbCr & "!!" & vbCr & "!!" & vbCr & "!!"
    
    Debug.Print x
    s(x)              ' to call the sub
    Debug.Print t(x)  ' to call the function

End Sub
```

Comment: You can get this down to a 48 byte immediate window function as `?"!";:For i=1To[Len(A1)]:?Mid([A1],i,1)"!";:Next`

Comment: @TaylorScott, I agree that would work in Excel VBA.  I was just thinking of a pure VBA solution.

Comment: If you want to keep it as a pure VBA function, you can still get it down a bit by switching it to a sub and printing directly to the console as `Sub t(x):Debug.?"!";:For i=1To Len(x):Debug.?Mid(x,i,1)"!";:Next:End Sub` or `Sub t(x):s="!":For i=1To Len(x):s=s+Mid(x,i,1)+"!":Next:Debug.?s:End Sub`

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>26</s> 16 bytes

```
"!"<>#&/@#<>"!"&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X0lRycZOWU3fQdnGDshW@x9QlJlXEq2sa5fm4JyRWJSYXJJaVOygHAtUUs2lZKhgpGCsYKJgqmCmpAPkGlmaWhoqACkDQyMQZWhkDqJMLYxA0iBsoMRV@x8A)

Input a list of characters. Returns a string.

Comment: it does not produce the result in a string format tho

Answer (score 3):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/?_ga=2.53425960.1250200544.1568106024-1670995612.1562682143), 50 bytes

```
fun f(s:String)=s.map{"!$it"}.joinToString("")+"!"
```

[Try it online!](https://play.kotlinlang.org/?_ga=2.92159770.1250200544.1568106024-1670995612.1562682143#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLjUwIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsImpzQ29kZSI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiLyoqXG4gKiBZb3UgY2FuIGVkaXQsIHJ1biwgYW5kIHNoYXJlIHRoaXMgY29kZS4gXG4gKiBwbGF5LmtvdGxpbmxhbmcub3JnIFxuICovXG5cbmZ1biBtYWluKCkge1x0XG4gICAgdmFsIHRlc3RDYXNlcyA9IGFycmF5T2YoXCIxIDIgMyA0IDUgNlwiLFxuXHRcdFx0XHRcdFx0XHRcIjEyOTU5MSAxMjkwMTIgMTI5MTI3IDEyOTU4MlwiLFxuICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIFwiXCIsXG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgXCIwXCIsXG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgXCIhIVwiLFxuICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgXHRcIiEhXCIpXG4gICAgdGVzdENhc2VzLmZvckVhY2h7XG4gICAgXHRwcmludGxuKGYoaXQpKSAgIFxuICAgIH1cbn1cblxuZnVuIGYoczpTdHJpbmcpe3MubWFwe1wiISRpdFwifS5qb2luVG9TdHJpbmcoXCJcIikrXCIhXCJ9XG4ifQ==)

This is my first participation on this site, thought I would try a challenge with my new favourite language.

Comment: [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@1@WmKOQZvu/utgquKQoMy9d165Yryi1ICcxOVVDSUlHSVFJs/Z/WmmeQm5iZp5GYlF6sZWCY1FRYqUNRL2dpkI1F2cBkFmSk6eRpqHkmVecWlSikJRaUp6amqekqclV@x8A "Kotlin – Try It Online") with replace and a lambda

Answer (score 3):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 18 bytes

```
%|092M3W!;~[;~!;~]
```

**Dion's solution.**

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/?code=%25%7C092M3W!%3B%7E%5B%3B%7E!%3B%7E%5D&input=Hello%20there)

#### Older solution(19 bytes):

```
%|0~[65W3M;;]65W3M;
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/?code=%25%7C092M3W!%3B%7E%5B%3B%7E!%3B%7E%5D&input=Hello%20there)

Comment: 18 bytes https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/?code=%25%7C092M3W!%3B~%5B%3B~!%3B~%5D&input=Hello%20there

Comment: Wow, lotta work for a byte.

Comment: Thats codegolf for ya :D

Comment: Argh! So close! Pushing a `!` character in 1+ is already 11 bytes anyway...

Answer (score 3):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 11 bytes

```
$>P...@1;,<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/1/FLkBPT8/B0FrH5v9/j9ScnHwA)

```
  $ > P
 . . . @
1 ; , < .
 . . . .
  . . .
```

- `P1` in place of `33` so that it resets the memory.
- MP is stationary

## (old) [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 17 bytes

```
{33...@;",<./{;/>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/7/a2FhPT8/BWknHRk@/2lrf7v//ktTiEoXkxOJUewA)

```
  { 3 3
 . . . @
; " , < .
 / { ; /
  > . .
```

`{33` Puts an ! in left memory

`;"` Prints ! at the start and sets back mem

`,` Gets the next byte of input, `<` sends the IP U-R if null (which terminates it with `@`), D-R else

`/{;/` Reflects IP, prints current byte, and sets it to the next line

`>` Redirects the IP to the start of the loop

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
¤\!V
```

```
 ¤\!V - Full program
-------
 ¤    - Push empty string to the stack
  \!  - Push exclamation mark to the stack, better than `!`
    V - take implicit input and replace the empty 
        string with the exclamation point
```

For an empty input, it will produce `!0!` because it considers the empty input 0, but I don't believe this can be fixed since taking input plainly returns 0 for "".

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C2%A4%5C!V&inputs=Hello%2C%20World!&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 bytes

```
rP'!
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=clAnIQ&input=IjEgMiAzIDQgNSA2CjEyOTU5MSAxMjkwMTIgMTI5MTI3IDEyOTU4MgoKMCI)

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 7 bytes

Unfortunately `!` is a reserved character, necessitating the quotation marks.

```
ï'! i'!
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=7ychIGknIQ&input=IjEgMiAzIDQgNSA2CjEyOTU5MSAxMjkwMTIgMTI5MTI3IDEyOTU4MgoKMCI)

Not much to explain: `ï` is Cartesian product and `i` prepends.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

-1 thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen). Takes input as a [list of characters](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/whats-a-string/8964#8964).

```
õ.ø'!ý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Fa9wzvUFQ/v/f8/WilRSUdBqRhEpIAIBRABFksDEVkgIh9EeKPKZoMIKxCRCiJi8uCCASCiCET4wE2FSCtgIcC2@IMILzjLFURY49cHdo4bXAtEIUIwG@6yArg30uF@KYAbUwyXKIB7LR@uA5tbEyGysQA) or  [Try it online! (with input as a string)](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/WF3x8F51Rb3DO/7/V1JSSixOUUhMy8r3VkjMtkrlyg4o8knhUgCCNH8vf1drMNPbzZ/L2y07tSArPb9AoTi9IDE/C6QiMQtoAAA)

Comment: [Are you a bit rusty golfing in 05AB1E? ;p](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190280/52210)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Perhaps (now that I think about it I kinda am) :(. But I never actually knew how to exploit `€` so I guess I'm fine.

Comment: Yeah, it's something new this version.. The regular map `ε` works the same as in the legacy, but the `€` keeps all values on the stack. So `€D` would duplicate each character for example, while still keeping a 1D list. Not sure who's idea that was (probably _Adnan_), but it's useful in some cases. :) In other cases it can be pretty annoying as well, though.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Interesting, thanks for the info (*ahem* *ahem* I do see it's useful sometimes :P)

Comment: -1 byte for your approach: `õ.ø'!ý` (surrounding with an empty string before joining).

Comment: Ah, thanks, this version was just a direct port of my initial 8-byter which used string input, so this wouldn't have worked before... Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 2):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 11 characters

```
\A=\!
?=?\!
```

Unfortunately `!` starts a comment in Gema, so must be escaped.

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ echo -ne '1 2 3 4 5 6\n129591 129012 129127 129582\n\n0' | gema '\A=\!;?=?\!'
!1! !2! !3! !4! !5! !6!
!1!2!9!5!9!1! !1!2!9!0!1!2! !1!2!9!1!2!7! !1!2!9!5!8!2!
!
!0!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/P8bRNkaRy97WPkbx/39DBSMFYwUTBVMFMy5DI0tTS0MFIGVgaASiDI3MQZSphREXlwEA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 bytes

```
rP'!
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=clAnIQ&input=IjEgMiAzIDQgNSA2CjEyOTU5MSAxMjkwMTIgMTI5MTI3IDEyOTU4MgoKMCI)

```
r      Replace
 P     all empty strings "" with
  '!   An exclamation mark (If '!' wasn't a special character in Japt I could remove the quote)
```

Comment: You'd only be able to ditch the `'` if the replacement were a number.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p`, 11 bytes

```perl
s/^|.\K/!/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YP65GL8ZbX1E//f9/QwUjBWMFEwVTBTMuQyNLU0tDBSBlYGgEogyNzEGUqYURF5fBv/yCksz8vOL/ugUA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

```
+\!s+R\!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/XztGsVg7KEbx/3@lxOIUhcS0rHxvhcRsq9SYvOyAIp@UmDwFIEjz9/J3tYawvd38Y/K83bJTC7LS8wsUitMLEvOzQGoSs5QA)

---

```
     Code | Explanation
----------+-------------------------------------
+\!s+R\!  | Code
+\!s+R\!Q | with implicit variables filled
----------+-------------------------------------
     R  Q | For each d in input, replace d with:
    +R\!  |  d+"!"
   s      | Join results on empty string
+\!       | Add "!" to beginning
          | Print (implicit)
```

Answer (score 2):

## **[C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>69 62</s> 50 bytes**

Saved 12 bytes, thanks to ErikF's suggestion:

```
f(char*s){for(printf("!");*s;)printf("%c!",*s++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtBCoAgEADvvWIVAtfyBX6gb8iWFZiGBh2kr7d56TgzDJmViNkr2lzWBatPWZ15j5dXUki0ulj8uSchR12GAe3DTcHh9qgQagfQ8rSEkOBOOcxt7B5@yQe3Fjb3Bw)

Comment: You can use the passed-in pointer to iterate through the string and put the first `printf` in the for loop to save 12 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtBCoAgEADvvWIVAtfyBX6gb8iWFZiGBh2kr7d56TgzDJmViNkr2lzWBatPWZ15j5dXUki0ulj8uSchR12GAe3DTcHh9qgQagfQ8rSEkOBOOcxt7B5@yQe3Fjb3Bw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: Great idea! I'll update it

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOk0jOSOxSKtYszrT1thY28jUTEurWFvbuqAoM68kTUMtU1PXUE0tTaNY07r2P1BIITcxM09DU6GaS0EhTUPJIzUnJ1@hPL8oJ0VJ05qr9v@/5LScxPTi/7rlAA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ceilingcat that is a completely different method. Should be posted as its own answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 12 bytes

```
'!',,@,.&'!'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1RXVdXQcdPTUgIz/mlxcXKnJGfkKaQq1VhCFXIYKRgrGCiYKpgpmXIZGlqaWhgpAysDQCEQZGpmDKFMLIy4uAy7N/wA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Aheui (esotope)](https://github.com/aheui/pyaheui), 61 bytes

```
붖다따삭바사빠맣삭붛
밙봆＠뫃선차희져썬뻐
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xILc38///1tmmvu5e8nrLhTdPa1xumvGla83rngtfLF4O422Zzvd4w8/WWtvd7Frxe3fymZcGbDSvezl3zZsGON71rXu@e8P9/YnGKQmJaVr63QmK2VSpXdkCRTwqXAhCk@Xv5u1qDmd5u/lzebtmpBVnp@QUKxekFiflZIBWJWQA)

Nice small aheui code.

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 17 bytes

```scala
_.replace("","!")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVDNbsIwDL77KeyeQPtRWyhQ0CbtAAfKVKQ9wBRo2tFWTdR006Rpz945BQYHdppwan/2F9exbbaiFK3a5HLb4LPYVSg/G1klBp@0/gL4ECWm05em3lXZw@MB29f7WupSbGXPcW4dcvotgOarpqx6KXOOhz4OcIgBjsDzwyD0kMH1fAueP7YQTHwAl5P7N2zAvKn3MsGNBPIIyWcdsA5ZA9YRWd6nkKOwy9hHbofHyNrxbxTQhBH4uGTfOTXp3P1Pzmt1AwuToEhzFaEophKKdb1KAFnSeBnPZ50bLWKIFoXUeaY0mkwLldsMkV9agiBDCY8iKKWcFEWdX9CUJA9U0JpqWnEGML8/KcW0ZJ3T7IyNaMEcdFjwv5qrZVxP851hT3NVxdyxhmD/2su6PO@VXyVewum71IKVv2zX3Hf7Aw)

-3b thanks to Jo King!
Thanks to Dr Y Wit for linking me to the fact that not enforcing typing is allowed, and for the working TIO link.

Comment: ah, you're right; fixing this.

Comment: Something like [this](https://tio.run/##tVDNbsIwDL77KeyeQPtRWyhQ0A47wIEyFWkPMAWadrRVEzWdNGnas3dOEIMDO004tT/7i@vYNntRi17tSrnv8EUcGpSfnWwyg89afwFkMsf8qR@8zV@79tAUw8dW6lrs5cDz7j3yhj2A5ouubgY5c16AIY5wjBFOIAjjKA6QwQ9CC0E4tRDNQgCfk4d3bMC8q486w50ECggpZB2xjlkj1glZPqSYo9hlHCPf4SmydvobRTRjBD4@2XfOTXoP/5PLWm5gYTIUeakSFNVcQrVtNxkgS56u0@XCuckqhWRVSV0WSqMptFClzRDltSUIMpTxKIJyKklR4vyK5iR5oIq21NKGM4D548kppTXrkhYXbEIr5sBhxf9qrlZwPc13hj3NVRVzpxqC/Vsv6/q8N36VeAnn71oLVv6yrrnv/gc) perhaps? I don't know Scala

Comment: oh? it looks like it compiles like this. Now I'm really sad we can't do `_.replace("","!")`. Nice one anyway :)

Comment: Actually, your answer does not fully comply with the rules because it's neither a program nor a function but rather just code snippet. However if you post a function literal `s=>s.replace("","!")` that would be shorter and more correct. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcopCskFpRkpqXUqzgWFCgUM3FVZaYo5BmFVxSlJmXbmsHpf8X29oV6xWlFuQkJqdqKCnpKCkqaf4vAMqV5ORppGkoKQBBmr@Xv6u1kqYmV@3//wA "Scala – Try It Online")

Comment: Maybe even `_.replace("","!")` would be OK. See https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3885/tips-for-golfing-in-scala

Comment: @DrYWit Thanks; I'll let still the current TIO link though, because `_.replace("","!")` does not work there (I tried earlier before my comment 3h ago).

Comment: Well, if you declare function val with the type then you can bind a function literal `_.replace("","!")` to it. Check my TIO link.

Comment: You're right! Now I'll be able to post Scala lambdas easily. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 79 bytes

```
[N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   S _Read_STDIN_as_character][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input][S N
S _Duplicate_input][S S S T S S T   N
_Push_9_tab][T  S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S S N
_If_0_jump_to_Label_END][S S S T    S S S S T   N
_Push_33_!][T   N
S S _Print_as_character][T  N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_END][S S S T  S S S S T   N
_Push_33_!][T   N
S S _Print_as_character]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

Since Whitespace inputs one character at a time, the input should contain a trailing tab (`\t`) so it knows when to stop reading characters and the input is done.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##VYxLDoAwCETXcIo5h651YU3qFYjWT7toY008flW6MoEJD2a49@NyOcnsSmHgrbcZxAQiUgZBuQrXhRJ/qgGuwd@pFMkLZPXRQELjOEznuOjH1Q62a3U0vWXTB5f8FhPyliT6zyGeHg) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Start LOOP:
  Character c = STDIN as character
  If(c == '\t'):
    Call function END
  Print '!'
  Print c
  Go to next iteration of loop

function END:
  print '!'
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 6 bytes

```
É'!\'!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7//9wp7pijLri///qhgpGCsYKJgqmCmbqXOqGRpamloYKQMrA0AhEGRqZgyhTCyOgLBAZqAMA)

### Explanation

Nothing fancy here, just a loop

```
É        for each character do the next 3 operations
 '!      push single character "!"
   \     swap top elements
    '!   push single character "!"
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/) (7.4), 31 bytes

Based on [Petah](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/29865/petah)'s comment.

```php
fn($s)=>preg_replace(__,'!',$s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/RSsMwFH2/X3FWCu1gjiVaddbqk3uwg4r41o0SuqSlHU1o5vfXpA7xcMk5OffcS2JaMz2/mtYQhRdpLxYZSooYOG5xhwT3xPg22TI42jDuifEHT8kjJ9pEK4qEPUGoTucQ/ZOk/mPcnwgOqngv3tJZ5ruC8l0vTddoA9sYoTufEN28wR@LBf0r5xxT9yqVTWqIQ7vMXswom2qU5ixqGVfVKnIh15hcTOlRirpFfP2FsJjVErJuNYLyy12Oh@EwzLYX5ae03@dfM8AaoYqvI2sE3rz5wxxJpx8)

---

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 52 bytes

```php
function($s){return'!'.join('!',str_split($s)).'!';}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9PS8QwEMXv8ymmpZAW1rKtVl3r4sk9WKEi3rqLhG6y/bMkIUlP4mevSV3EYch7@fEmZFSn5scn1SmAyDJjDW6xAZJhjtd4gwXeQpZvik2GTtZZ7iXL77wU9znAmqyAUHNEygdZIR0fGIxv@vUI6IrXL/VzudhqV0O1G5kaTlKhOSkqB5@gw/KCP4IA/rUjh9L9im9nPonW9lLEkUm@NLOTFiQg6SB7ETuzMlZ/GnXurQ8kqUPl9@xmudSMth3Gl9WowcUlyNpOYth8uMthL/Ziwd4078xM518YYooRjy8jKYYeXv3VEinnHw)

Comment: PHP 7.4 `fn($s)=>preg_replace('//', '!', $s);`

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 75 bytes

Full program.

```php
foreach(file('php://stdin')as$e)echo'!'.implode("!",str_split($e));echo"!";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCsMgEEbhfW6RUFChNIvumtIcJYQ46l9tR0bp9a3ZvMXHyyG355p7HQvtR9AOibTq8pjnUi2@yuzlQoaOwGpUN3xyYkt6GqdrqbKVnFB1H8xyLp2Xtr4a4e0iwfMdHsKDhcRflIgzfijswAIX/w)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 100 bytes

```php
foreach(explode("\n",file_get_contents('php://stdin'))as$e)echo'!'.implode("!",str_split($e))."!\n";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBCgIhFADv@xdKoMKye@hW0f5IIIv71JfmE5Xo782gy5xmJvvcb1setFRgN17CJ0c6QPJH4rPFCNpB04ZSg9SqFMO9rGttByah1F5PoMB4Ekws@PqnjM@1FV1zxCaHoBbOxu7at3sHfNoA6OiMDgtNB5bwDiXgD26qZJEK2vAF)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 117 bytes

```php
foreach(explode("\n",file_get_contents('php://stdin'))as$e){echo'!';foreach(str_split($e)as$c)echo $c."!";echo "\n";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxRC8IgFEbf9yuaDFSI9tBbi/ZHAhnu6m4Or6hEEP1206CXwwff4YQtlOscKg1FWPQm4BV2WkGwu2dHgzsoC1lp8hl8ToJX9zKOKa/ouZRLGkC@QW/Eez79GylHlcKOWdS3Klo24zDoE@vZ9NstP33KfCuAD@MALZ3RYqRuxeieLjpssF0igxTRuC8)

Comment: Instead of `echo'!'.implode("!",str_split($e));echo"!";`, you can do `echo'!',join("!",str_split($e)),"!";`, which should save 7 bytes (read about `join()` on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.join.php). According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php you can just use the constant `STDIN` (I don't know how if will work).

Comment: I did that intentionally , for saving bytes i removed brackets and i want to echo "!" after the foreach loop.

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right. I missed that. But if you are reading line by line, you should output the newlines as well, except for the last one. `echo` doesn't output newlines, so, everything should be in the same line. You can use `echo'!',join('!',str_split(file_get_contents('php://stdin'))),'!';`, which is only 66 bytes long (or less, if the constant `STDIN` works) and fixes that.

Comment: I mean, `echo` doesn't automatically outputs newlines at the end, so, if you read line by line, you have to output the newline, if it isn't in the input.

Comment: file() returns an array of strings , each string has a newline as last character . @IsmaelMiguel

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), <strike>40</strike> 39 bytes

```forth
: f ." !"bounds do i 1 type ." !"loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU9LDsIgFNx7iin7GkHrr3GpC2tSD8AGpVRbA6S1C09fH1YXJjoJmTePmSEY19wvcWkC9f0aBmOGiJ1cZ3UL7XAFx/3hi2F/c84jJZ8PevML7NxA6M4PKRJkjANYEOa9@RtNR61k9KbAFDMkmENaLlbJioNowkUgLhaBkqWQVtoJg3@lVKuhTOUyqHpdSFsfm4OWFgST7/NtOszZLpc229WFr0r6Tlt65argUdWriYo@jVEk7fehm/4J)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f           \ start a new word definition
  ." !"bounds \ print ! and place the ending address on the stack
  do          \ start a counted loop from start-addr to end-addr      
    i         \ get address of current char
    1 type    \ print the char at the given address
    ." !"     \ print !
  loop        \ end the loop
;             \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 2):

## Emacs Lisp, 41 bytes

```lisp
(while(or(insert"!")(not(forward-char))))
```

Assuming input is received as the contents of the current buffer

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>48</s> <s>45</s> 39 bytes

```c
f(char*s){printf("!%.1s",s++)>1&&f(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7BDsIgEETvfAVuYgO2akGrNqg/UntoiCgH26bgRcK3I1Sz2bzZzCYzcv2QMgRF5LObVoa6cdK9VQQWyw0zUJg8p1eWZYoYKnx4dbon1KH52zbtxSG49b@BAgHDHO/wHlf4MJ@8rmqGI0rGExg/JlQnnuy0JSAvkBomEnOxvpRCn43@3AdFLN3@1RxHhY5lHIpGo1sq0Pi2hgBE5ZEPXw)

-3 thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/455506?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 26 bytes

```python
lambda x:x.replace('','!')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BbsIwEETv@xUbX5JUFMWmoSWII0htKqX3toeF2JQEbMu2VPr1aRwurFZ6o9HsaO1f@DF6MajN13Cmy74lvFbXuZP2TAeZpeksTdJ8CNIHjxv8ZK/aSxdwL8OvlJrNgDHGUeACn7DEJXCxKlccRxRcRHDxHFG@CIBiDE8X5Fsk1Zkaqa8k9B/uvQUcRzVvzXY9yXrXQL3rpe2OxqI/WjJdTFB3a6FbVZLA3Y4GfAOAMg7j03jSE301dVp30iFjj@xBFPmdo7IYyvPhHw)

Comment: This exact answer has already been posted by Waterbyte

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
?⑷\!⑸\!^
```

Using a mapping approach really does help

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///f/tHE7TGKjybuiFGM@/8/sThFITEtK99bITHbKhUA)

### Answer History

#### 9 bytes

```
?^(\!')\!
```

Pretty much a port of the MathGolf submission.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fPk4jRlFdM0bx/39DI0tTS0MFIGVgaASiDI3MQZSphREA)

Comment: I think the explicit `?` is not needed.

Comment: No. It isn't. Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 21 bytes

```powershell
"$args"-replace"","!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcUxCoAwDADAva@IQeii0ESr9jlFgg4FSzr4/Ghvufq8ou2WUsxwzHo1nFVqyacgTjigmXkChgVWiLA54hQTwV8g7hHvvXiwc8F/)

Boring regex `replace`ment is boring. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
"!"w.∋w?w⊥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf/XBXp1JBUX5KaXJqsZUSkGdf96htw6OmpkcdK5T0uLhAQrUPt074r6SoVK73qKO73L78UdfS//@jlbiAQElHyVDBSMFYwUTBVMGMy9DI0tTSUAFIGRgagShDI3MQZWphxMVlAFScWJyikJiWle@tkJhtlcqVHVDkk8KlAARp/l7@rtZgprebP5e3W3ZqQVZ6foFCcXpBYn4WSEViFsgAIFZU5EJCSrH/AQ)

Takes input through the *output* variable, and unifies the input variable with `"!"`, printing the output.

```
"!"w          Print "!", which is the input variable.
    .∋w       Print an element of the output variable.
       ?w     Print the input variable again.
         ⊥    Fail.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 54 bytes

```
(()){({}<>)((((()()()()){}){}){}())<>}<>{({}<>)<>}<>{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0NDU7Nao7rWxk5TAwQ0IVCzuhaCgEwbO6AsVA2EXfv/v2tFck5ibmJJZn6egm9iUfZ/3WQA)

**Code:**

```
(())                            push 1, so the loop runs at least one time
{                               while stack 1 isn't empty
    ({}<>)                      move letter to stack 2
    ((((()()()()){}){}){}())    push 33 (Exclamation Mark) on stack 2
    <>                          return to stack 1 for checking if the end is reached
}
<>{({}<>)<>}                    move everything from stack 2 back to stack 1 (otherwise the text would be reversed)
<>{}                            switch to stack 1 and delete leading 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 9 bytes

```
L:33{;33"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/9/Hyti42trYWOn///9KHqk5OflKAA)

```
L:   ;        \ len(input) times do:
  33          \    Append character 33 (exclamation mark)
    {         \    Cyclically shift the string left once
      33      \ Append character 33 again
        "     \ Print the result
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (27 bytes)

My first code golf, 27 bytes in Javascript. Could probably shave some more bytes off, but I'm not too sure.

```
f={x:s=>`!${s.join('!')}!`}
```

**Example Usage**

```
console.log(f.x('1 2 3 4 5'.split('')))
// Output: !1! !2! !3! !4! !5!
```

Comment: Welcome to CCGC! Using the way of defining lambdas that has been kind of standardized on this site, this is 21 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLCoAgEADQq4wQjC4S@i3tLIppKOJIE22is9t72T2O/ZXaPVY6Qo@ms9mtGF7WmVKVKFB9wnZPlakEXeiUUeIEMyywwoaaW0m3RFRK9R8 "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online") (unless the lambda is called recursively, the `f=` does not need to be counted)

Answer (score 2):

## 1+, <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
1##11"+""*"**+;,;1#
```

1+ 19 vs 18 MAWP

Error-terminating because comparison is expensive.

Comment: I think i'm winning for now ;) btw, mawp submissions should be here https://github.com/8Dion8/8Dion8.github.io/blob/master/scraper/posts.txt

Comment: @Dion Yeah, only 1 byte away! I'm creating the 1+ answer list now.

Comment: I created a python script to gather everything... Maybe you could change it a bit and use it for gathering 1+ answers? If you are interested, ill clean up the code so its understandable xd

Comment: @Dion Apparently your script searches for 1+ with the SE search tool but that will not work well for 1+. [Manual 1+ answer list](https://esolangs.org/wiki/1%2B/Programs)

Comment: https://github.com/8Dion8/8Dion8.github.io/blob/master/scraper/scraper.py is the current script

Comment: Cleaned up the code and added comments

Comment: @Dion Can you change the format to the format in my answer list (including scoreboard)

Comment: I can try, will take a bit of time though

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

-1 byte from @ngn's savings

```
{x,/y,'x}"!"
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6qu0NGv1FGvqFVSVOLiSlMyVDBSMFYwUTBVMFMCcY0sTS0NFYCUgaERiDI0MgdRphZGIGkgdtBRMlACAD0LDps=)

Creates a function projection, with `x` fixed to `"!"`.

- `y,'x` pair-wise append an exclamation mark to each character in the input
- `x,/` flatten the list, using "!" as the seed (to prepend the leading "!")

Comment: save a byte by turning `"!"` into a curried argument: [`f:{x,/y,'x}"!"`](https://tio.run/##FckxDoAgDAXQq9S/oAlGWgVF7oODCTPGePYK0xvePZerqObzrXZ5rKkfBmg2I5iEVtrIU0ACS/SRqeFYOix7xx/SFsnCYdIf)

Answer (score 2):

## AWK, 11 bytes

```
gsub(_,"!")
```

```
 echo '
1 2 3 4 5 6
129591 129012 129127 129582

0
asd afjoK ak:e
kPrLd
    fOJOE;
    KFO
KFkepjgop sgpaoj   faj
!!
!!
!!
!!
!!' | awk 'gsub(_,"!")'
```

---

```
!1! !2! !3! !4! !5! !6!
!1!2!9!5!9!1! !1!2!9!0!1!2! !1!2!9!1!2!7! !1!2!9!5!8!2!
!
!0!
!a!s!d! !a!f!j!o!K! !a!k!:!e!
!k!P!r!L!d!
! ! ! ! !f!O!J!O!E!;!
! ! ! ! !K!F!O!
!K!F!k!e!p!j!g!o!p! !s!g!p!a!o!j! ! ! !f!a!j!
!!!!!
!!!!!
!!!!!
!!!!!
!!!!!
```

Comment: It doesn’t work

Comment: i've cleaned up your answer formatting. In the future, please try to make it clear which part of your submission is your actual answer. (side note: this is almost identical to a [previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225406/76162))

Comment: @Hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian This seems to work fine, why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: @mousetail it works now, but it didn’t before with the word “awk” in front of it.

Comment: @Hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian Copy pasting the code before the edit in bash already gave the correct solution even before the edit

Comment: @mousetail I used TIO

Comment: @Hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian It works fine in TIO: https://tio.run/##TcqxDoIwGATg/X@Kg6WaONBqRXSWQUzwDcyPFEg7tLExLr57BScvl3w3XMdxSgnmMXkIklDYYgeNPUlV6UpippBqQapyQR8UUUEce/BgfQN2R0Pu9rz2hDlDe2nPp99s6paa2plgRx8Qx8DeLg@2lGX/FfiA3w5ijK9udd/kWb4WKX0B

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 30 Bytes

```python
lambda x:'!%s!'%'!'.join([*x])
```

It feels like these methods were designed for the challenge!

### -1 from Jacob (now noodle man) by using ***the cursed `%`*** (Dun dun dun!)

### -3 from Glorfindel for using a starred method for conversion!

#### [**!T!r!y! !r!u!n!n!i!n!g! !i!t! !o!n!l!i!n!e!**](https://tio.run/##DcJBCoAgEADAr@hB1A5dugW9pDqspGToKrqFvd5iJr90Jpy6W7YeIJoDWJslF5VLIbkcr@RRrUPbdc/FIymnPOablNa6G8AfI9vIMl9ZhPLYENJdPw)

Comment: [Here's 33](https://tio.run/##DcgxDoAgDADAr8BAKIuLm4k/cYGIsQYKgWLw9Uhuu/zxnWgd136MYKM7reiblqpKrbTUy5OQIGBl6MaMXJAYLkDKjcHMcZYmwb6zF1hFtOX1IaRWfw "Python 3 – Try It Online"), I don't know much python so it can likely be golfed further

Comment: `list(...)` can always be `[*...]` instead

Comment: [27 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcIxDoAgDADAr5SBAIuLm4k/cYEIEQOFQDH4@mru6ktXwZXDfnCy2Z0W5qaE7EJJJdRyl4h6Gq4tIumgI9ZB2hjDzuIPyE/yEDtk2x6fUhn9Aw) - you don't even need to convert it to a list, since any iterable will work.

Answer (score 2):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 67 bytes

```
listen to S
while S
cut S
join S with "!"
say "!"+S+"!"
listen to S
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 29 Bytes

```
print('',*input(),'',sep="!")
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ11dRyszr6C0RENTB8guTi2wVVJU0vz/31DBSMFYwUTBVMEMAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 6 bytes

```
⭆Ｓ⁺!ι!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaHjmFZSWQLgamjoKATmlxRpKiko6CpmamprWXBDlQAFN6///o5WUlAwVjBSMFUwUTBXMuAyNLE0tDRWAlIGhEYgyNDIHUaYWRlxcBkDFsf91y3IA) Link is to verbose version of code. Works on empty strings too. Input format is somewhat cumbersome due to Charcoal's lack of EOF. Works by preceding each character with a `!` and then suffixing a final `!` on the end. Alternative version, also 6 bytes:

```
⪫!!⪫Ｓ!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaHjmFZSWQLgamjoKATmlxRpKiko6CpmamprWXBDlQAFN6///o5WUlAwVjBSMFUwUTBXMuAyNLE0tDRWAlIGhEYgyNDIHUaYWRlxcBkDFsf91y3IA) Link is to verbose version of code. Works by joining the characters on `!` and then wrapping them in `!!`.

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 94 bytes

```
I	I =INPUT	:F(END)
S	I LEN(1) . X REM . I	:F(O)
	O ='!' O X	:(S)
O	OUTPUT =O '!'
	O =	:(I)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/35PTU8HW0y8gNITTyk3D1c9FkysYKOTj6qdhqKmgpxChEOTqC6Q9QdL@mlyc/gq26orqCv4KEZxWGsGaXP6c/qEhQO0Ktv4KQAmwAqCMpyYX0LD//x25nLicuQA)

Prints with an additional trailing newline (as SNOBOL always prints a line break). The way input is consumed, there is no way of distinguishing between a final line ending in `\n` or not.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
_z'!R
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=_z%27!R&i=1+2+3+4+5+6%0A129591+129012+129127+129582%0A%0A0&a=1)

Replace `""` with `"!"` using regex replacement.  I don't exactly understand why this works.

*Edit:* Found it in the Ecma spec: [15.5.4.10](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf)

> If there is a match with an emptystring   (in   other   words,   if   the   value   of *regexp*.**lastIndex** is   left   unchanged),   increment *regexp*.**lastIndex** by 1.

**Old Stuff:**

I <s>would</s> have been able to get to 5 bytes <s>in either of two scenarios.</s>

1. If input was provided in an escaped literal e.g. `"line1\nline2"`.  But I opted against that for the sake of "usability".
2. If there was not a <s>bug</s> *feature* in stax's zip implementation when encountering empty strings/arrays.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>49</s> <s>48</s> 42 bytes

```
#~StringSplit~""~StringRiffle~{a="!",a,a}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X7kuuKQoMy89uCAns6ROSQnKDcpMS8tJratOtFVSVNJJ1EmsVfsfAJQoiVbWtUtzUI5V03eo5lIyVDBSMFYwUTBVMFPSAXKNLE0tDRWAlIGhEYgyNDIHUaYWRiBpBRBhoMRV@x8A)

-6 bytes thanks to @attinat

Comment: The code in the Header, Code, and Footer sections is run.
You can use infix notation and drop the `{ }` in `StringSplit` for [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X7kuuKQoMy89uCAns6ROSQnKDcpMS8tJratOtFVSVNJJ1EmsVfsfAJQoiVbWtUtzUI5V03eo5lIyVDBSMFYwUTBVMFPSAXKNLE0tDRWAlIGhEYgyNDIHUaYWRiBpBRBhoMRV@x8A)

Comment: @attinat Thanks that helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

## [C#](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/), 142 bytes

```
public class P{public static void Main(string[]a){System.Console.Write("!");foreach(char c in a[0]){System.Console.Write(c.ToString()+"!");}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Elvish](https://elv.sh), 32 bytes

```
use re;re:replace "" "!" (slurp)
```

Copy and paste into the [Live Environment](https://try.elv.sh) to try it out!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Would it be possible to edit in a link to an online interpreter, such as [Try it online!](https://www.tio.run) so that other users can verify your program?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I added a link to the provided live environment.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 32 bytes

```c
f(s){printf("!%s",s)-1&&f(s+4);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9No1izuqAoM68kTUNJUbVYSadYU9dQTQ0orm2iaV37PzcxM09DU4GrmksBCNI0fJQMjYyVNK0VwPyC0pJiDSUgFy7rkZqTk68Qnl@UkwISrv0PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 12 bytes

```
~irj!'~
@Wu<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/78usyhLUb2OyyG81Ob//8SkZAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 31 bytes

```
print((io.read():gsub("","!")))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 47 bytes

```
func[s][parse s[insert"!"any[skip insert"!"]]s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYuxDsIgEIb3PsXJExS0atvZDtakxpUwEIGmkFDC1cGnx3ZR4i3ff9/dH7VKD624KEyTzMs/OQoeZEQNyCePOi5kR6R/c3RTgK8RAkUKcfILGCAUGOzhABUcSfGzrK5qCitKyjZQdtpQnVn2lcUyyxIVSGPnHqRrdHZw93hT2Q7rmOE6XNo/2XdDZvrO6WDHOQCOQc52a0lL0gc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 5 bytes

```
aJW'!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/0StcXfH///@KilxICAA)

The `JW` builtin was made for challenges like this.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 12 bytes

```sh
<<<${1///!}!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsZGpdpQX19fsVbx////Gak5OfkKJRmpRakA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Branch](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/branch-lang/), 11 bytes

```
33.,[.33.,]
```

Try it on the [online Branch interpreter](https://branch.hyper-neutrino.xyz/#WyIzMy4sWy4zMy4sXSIsImFzZCBhZmpvSyBhazplXG5rUHJMZFxuICAgIGZPSk9FO1xuICAgIEtGT1xuS0ZrZXBqZ29wIHNncGFvaiAgIGZhaiIsIiJd)!

Put 33 on the tree and output (`!`). Then, grab input. Finally, while that value is not EOF, output it, output 33 (`!`), and grab input again.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org), 13 bytes

```
:%s/\_./!&/g
```

Works by putting a `!` before every character, including newline characters. The TIO version doesn't work properly for the 4 newline testcase, but it does work in Vim.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/30q1WD8mXk9fUU0/nev/f4/UnJx8Ha7w/KKcFEUA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Subleq](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Subleq) (8-bit), <s>12</s>11 bytes

*-1 byte for removing last 0*

```
2 -1 33
-1 8 -1
8 -1 0
8 8
```

[Subleq emulator](http://mazonka.com/subleq/online/hsqjs.cgi)

### Explanation

```
0:  2 -1 33 ' Output 2: (char(33)); 3rd argument is not used for output so use it for memory
3: -1  8 -1 ' Read input to 8:, exit if null
6:  8 -1  0 ' Output 8:
9:  8  8    ' 8: = 0 goto 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## BRASCA, <s>14</s> 13 bytes

-1 byte thanks to RezNesX

```
,![$'!oo{]'!o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVt7c9s2Ev9fnwKx20qqJVvOo0l8lnt2kl7dNnHGdud643FZSIQkpiTBkKBlT9p@9dwu@BBBQiIYPz3TxiaB3d8@sQCWwZWYcf/JiyD87HgBDwWJrqIe8aiYtSYh94hwPEayVy5jQfI4pL4N/6Qv8C/4b8pa6QMR0jEb0fGfrdbYpVFEDkIajekr/H2nReBnbW3tRMCAHgnZ1IkECyMCVMgFDR06clkEA@RAm02IZTm@IyyrEzF30t1pyRf4sy5pyIk5mfwlDt6M5IAhOTtXn1N4NlAfjZRHCx77ISNzBgyo7fhTwi5YCFrDX2lExjMKsiLf78uMQxhiedxmQPcH6kasgPu9EzC77/jEpoLmj50J8bk0AUwHZptORIW46nR38iEF@jDAwulAfjEDUXa6Zzs7/e1zZdKEh8TqEYsAU@bHHgupYJ0SqRIjDTO0VxS7Apmqb86QZa/ytIxDtcwmDQLm2x0e2p2EcLebD2egszrJwUsWWv2RohOlxhkx5pMAjCCYTa6YKNmHuqiqKysbUbXR6cyJyNxxXRIJDj5A4TcxY2QEBv@TCRLwyBEO90seN585LrNczoMIiH76W6HIyBgdAh0WSQUcmYcqARxhpW@qXjpOHKoot3wOkec6Y4gSsG0ujH6E4IEq7vr7OJoRmDgCjoJLaNI8eQQGMMBKBkif6eHogrdULYrvi9QvqBszwieLiEFOGi74PuWBv65kgm4jB3WXCzLiQkCqAs4rxbKScXXSOX7EQtEZJEPqBTRCgDNU/sslXwCoCg92ldm5xIIHWeIsJ5qcrBpmIRNx6Bc8rxqJ6ZACMGSTxG4JTa0KeFAU/g5gDjKNnUAYI6Bs8cgxRUxY2cPUJNmfKr7sKRlCTNI1TbqiWapcKCjBWp490s0eVWcXfK6IvR2lLqgNYEx2NyWREoKJjF293IOm4lZJj7p6pQxSEx7jehwxrcjyTdmpCnyyEd2clvQWJOUyfypmeodN3pXppq4GLzsLFoXQjF1YcCU1uUIQXCGIC/ognfK60c1ZjWLHtZOHZX6CeYFa2OATC@oOpeZQX8LC6LKPMRdMsQ4WB9lyBsmHex6uUNVKARefUo0AZq2Q3iODaiFRGdUfkm1llPSRKs7hcmolWcvAMkHQ3c7WklVXmZdO1JPP3DBTTLcKtsjgvBED8I4QiyjJSM0My6qJMznnHCZliOqnZCNxlpy@Wob2Wq2mT8OY1dt2SB6v5vRHY3MUh1VAmNLHifXkU29q4R7k5AoylkdoOIVI8AVsXwK5Z8IyELY0m8EVmZDdCajcpx7bq74dk10Mm71W65RDPOHmBkJ7FE97JIa8NbG3xhhqwIXamG8mW@NNHBq5fE5sPvcJj0UQi3R4tDWOJDAH90XI07KkxJblUaiLrdSECQAwRGHrlTpZii2vJNc@9x6dfdV@xPmnc/j/53R/lmQucoApKMmJmLE8GhSJFBNUluzIWwAiR8u/k3RXYJoXt7syWxbeFNNbeKUaKrdukdSZhux5OQ2kY5Qd2VJXqzxYJ3Kp3YVMuKeWrCuyzUATSAWtFcvpQTXyK968bU5u24DcY3Nyjw3IPTEn98SA3FNzck8NyD0zJ/fMgNx35uS@MyD33JzccwNyL8zJvTAg99Kc3EsDcm4DNzYJi18a0DPxPNYgLkyM@6ZBYJgEmt0gMkzM@7qBL5vExqyBu5h4849N/MXEYX5uRNCE4qe1HbL@mo1DhtWBKfHsEdZ9fZOM/TeyOfSvwWbDhE2IbORydyyPc3V86GIF1tetEozJINx1OLjLkGfHnVGPUECpt9ASCZ1uq7pgSwGS1R6qpRkNawVv/9Fe6RjqYa62BDaqpctSyLOumnJmY/u8u4qQUlFt4J6qqpG3FPeyAe7keOGEfCn2DfSDfdu@ZQfQuewGNfDTPuI7iUd4zyDuAWTfBOS3CPJt7AoncK/uAeS3JiC3ksQi2BS8x3YunEi3r7x9sFtbJmi/lirlduzye8D4tQnE3xHim8uA@8sS9S1b3cjskQygj@F1EFaZ47Xh5gQ2fumvETDo0G5Xl6QPHDF3YEPbICv9g6DfHZ3eKOZ/TNT1jcyH717fgz2/McH3F@I7Or4HeH@ZwLMQ3m/3gu93wKfxvhPtJr4CnCLwQJ6088Xp9f7KUqF4cwAEDNQz0nI5MOcyMuGyL7lklzJmwqi3BmbSHOj5HDTgYyRPD/mkJ/hLDmUUDtlRfy3hHSRsx3hZKk/sQRQ@WcHhSzMPvc7ICup/qagXF26mwLM7OFNU2Xh6AxMq0ngojccvVPVjfCREtCyT668vMkaGTZIwwPc2x1dStLx9Sw8@6/E11bkxvqBGf8SXnT2R3i88HvvCdAfnL3Zwg14ydcUezthGN2On9zV2ekB6WO0L1/SH72WyTJq20vaIQX/78XNTv8s7vDqwzyyfK3QNADzK17jFzWpt0tacZaR3ryYsv0KW0ZwG0tBizokjmBcR7l87md96xh8ZyHcsbcpFtkiJWcjY3co4vnVFjK@jMu19TkWPJ6jHMfdx3fRzZYK7JISju/cTjLFIoEgb@A81irBpWYzlDpC2DiCbdnvzA3d8yc7vLhJZfvCFTQzLk94Y0xwkk0LqK1zppbPrT/SaKAfBG6jDSdUBZZ8gQMRxMOWnua/T152PK0L10hStNEEoci0XC6Akk/eG5OmLtK8V/94dkmfPl89TThyBxZlEgnf3cjqArpf7sCj3ohMu0UBn487kHqhiv/xiqQFyq17sS1n@OkAktOtL9pV@V6H9W5G2SWFtsqhXuMTI5Ve/f6Il6ZuWIbJtJ4nmZifpkAxskzzza4pzuhRnMadcJjnlspJTWnVuoPY23bSYmjOBw60jA0fj8qhFdmRg//f@yavDw7TPsc7rFq0Ilebjpe0IJVGqXcvaywj8kUM645l6DdTtQVjbw3bbwNJHS0U1CYL7lzYPviZC@6rQaQZ9uAYuGreBmO@Wi/lQjasx7EJgTTy/4r4IuUt@cPm8XiG7qJBfWBRBHU1v@wYE1bdLGyWubT0lZqLqpu1Ge6iL/4B5ZBP73ahj7@GqYyivdD7G4NZ3oIjh8MFqov2/NmjigIk5Y/5D2FqivrC6HOP/Hq4D/Rsd6JSFnoMbs9bNJEX85otdOsKktlxHAJAPbdkMTF3yIfaCmsQutY56HdTqo9qCUIvoAyL6CVBgNTeHwjpq0uOg9s/Uc/sp54YfJTZj11fZbRiwO0N2/8W2177sma12XlfVndS8j7DoXbnBUnZK/e3zGgstkyoXqtgtXttMq5X2vCQtLMm3JeverYpq4kmvVnf1lL7CM@sUOjWkmXy3J2m21J1L8pWKlCIImTyQifIPVvGjyLQdqtozr@@N1rfJr5/iBy6OgNJwQuYz5sMWnwPjUEaVcMCmwHYCu3e7pj@6Wb@V@iFLjuYIWcseAnmu7IiWeTKvNGGl4EqdCutv5RVK9tlm@XNNoxTILscsEORndjXikHiw1yYM40CUvn6qZvN04hv5D6RtNGRJnPUT7rHkc9c58wWZh9yf9vAkmM/BOAQ4cRVuUkqvvTk@PjreIbrppbvXZEL@QfcmpGuPCgvAlQ/hCyIk3wEcpo6bfsDQarpxWIxVQgB8TLPDWHnPe42jSjpcWYVoMGLo6zFWN6u0bs@2hLg@QBe0aZWsllyqzyq5FWI3Frle3OaiLhUTfz7LT7cdzHuCReL/)

### Explanation

```
,               - Reverse stack
 ![$    {]      - Loop stack length:
    '!oo        -     Print "!" followed by the next letter
          '!o   - Print the last "!"
```

Comment: 13 bytes: `,![$'!oo{]'!o`

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 105 bytes

```go
import."regexp"
func f(s[]byte)[]byte{return append(MustCompile(`(?s).`).ReplaceAll(s,[]byte(`!$0`)),33)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lZDNSsQwFIVxm6e4DQo3UEt_rDOzEnEtiFtHSKxJKbZpaFIYGXwSN0XwIXwUfRrbyTgMOhtDwoGb3O-cm9e3sh0-jCieRCmhEZUmVWPazkVUNY6-906dzj-rn1onS7kylKheF6DQ3t0_PDvJvKw76fpOgzBG6ke87q27ahtT1RI5XlgWcRbdSlOLQl7WNdrQtyEPjmPOWJhl7MUbfh3NNg5THmSwJjddpV2tkcqVaEwtaQjWjbUSFW4puys2Lt-APIEUMjiDHM5Jki7yRQKjxEk6SZLOJsnnKSExD4Eu9QHufxijs8fsAgQB2ds83Hj8sfj1asLsURTSE7vU0xnzUXFoeOHH3v7fMHj9Bg)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 44 bytes

```
="!"&CONCAT(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)&"!")
```

- `"!"` is just the first `!`.
- `CONCAT(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)&"!")`

  - `SEQUENCE(LEN(A1))` creates an array `1, 2, ... X` where `X` is the length of the input.
  - `MID(A1,SEQUENCE(~),1)` pulls the n<sup>th</sup> character from the input.
  - `MID(~)&"!"` adds `!` after every one of those characters.
  - `CONCAT(MID(~)&"!")` combines all those n<sup>th</sup> character + `!` into one string.

[image: Screenshot]

<sup>Note: The line breaks are there with or without Word Wrap turned on but it won't look right until you turn it on. The screenshot has Word Wrap turned on.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org),  <sup><s>31</s></sup>  28 bytes

```factor
[ 33 interleaved [I !${}!I]]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=JY29DoIwFEb3PsWFuOrCYmAWgxgxMU6E4QZuidC0tS3GxPgkLgzqU_givo0__ZZzhpN8tyfH2ikzvuV-l22WMRykI6OVQEfQk5EkwNJxIFmTndHZGbSQMBaibQB5p3LAPibWb826YfAdL1bFIvlrnhYsT3vSXas02Faj6n4FduFjcHw6f5UQRf5SEJ6ogTKDYHK5BllV-eReoxBex9HzAw)

- `33 interleaved` Insert an exclamation point between each character of the input.
- `[I !${}!I]` Interpolate the above string into the `${}`, adding exclamation points to the beginning and end, and print.

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 11 bytes

```
'!'⊸(⊣∾´∾¨)
```

Anonymous tacit function that takes and returns a string. [Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgJyEn4oq4KOKKo+KIvsK04oi+wqgpCgpGICJhYgpjZCI=)

#### Explanation

```
'!'⊸(⊣∾´∾¨)
    (      )  Call the following function with the original argument on the right
'!'⊸          and '!' on the left:
         ∾¨     Concatenate each (prepends '!' to each character, resulting
                in a list of two-character strings)
       ∾´       Right-fold that list on concatenation
     ⊣          with a starting value of the left argument (i.e. '!')
```

---

A port of [Sʨɠɠan's APL solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253709/16766) is also 11 bytes:

```
(∾⊢∾∾¨)⟜'!'
```

[Try it!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RyDihpAgKOKIvuKKouKIvuKIvsKoKeKfnCchJwoKRyAiYWIKY2Qi)

Answer (score 1):

## [(,)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/(,)) <s>111</s> 91 Chars or \$91\log_{256}(3)\approx18.03\$ Bytes

```
((),()()()()()()()())((),(())(())(())(())())(,,,(()()),(,(()(),((()()())),,(())))(()()),())
```

[TIO](https://inparencomma.pythonanywhere.com/?code=((),()()()()()()()())((),(())(())(())(())())(,,,(()()),(,(()(),((()()())),,(())))(()()),())&stdin=cat)

Answer (score 1):

### C, 42 bytes

```
f(char *s){printf("!%c",*s);if(*s++)f(s);}
```

Essentially to not have to have two printf statments I have the printf run on the null byte of the string which prints the '!' but the null byte is ignored.

**Easier to read**

```
f(char *s){
  // Prints ! and char of string
  printf("!%c", *s);
 
  // If more string than recurse for next char
  if(*s != 0) f(s+1);
}
```

Comment: I don't know much C, would removing that space be valid?

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

<sup>*-2 bytes thanks to [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214)!*</sup>

```
`:'!ṁe'!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fm18erPOoqfF/gpW64sOdjanqiv///49WismDQCUdJUMFIwVjBRMFUwUzEM/I0tTSUAFIGRgagShDI3MQZWphBJQFIgMgTixOUUhMy8r3VkjMtkoFCmQHFPmkAGkFIEjz9/J3tYZyvN38gSxvt@zUgqz0/AKF4vSCxPwskKrELJBBQKyoqBQLAA)

Answer (score 0):

## x86-16 machine code, 8 bytes

```
00000000: b021 aaa4 aae2 fcc3                      .!......
```

Listing:

```
B0 21       MOV  AL, '!'        ; character to insert
AA          STOSB               ; write first ! to output string  
        CLOOP: 
A4          MOVSB               ; copy input char to output string 
AA          STOSB               ; write ! to output string 
E2 FC       LOOP CLOOP          ; loop until end of input 
C3          RET                 ; return to caller
```

Callable function, input at `SI`, length in `CX`.  Output to string at `DI`.

Test runs:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), <sup><s>21</s> <s>20</s></sup>  19 bytes

```
x->'!'join(x,!)*'!'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZvu/QtdOXVE9Kz8zT6NCR1FTC8j5X1CUmVeikaahpKTElVicopCYlpXvrZCYbZXKxZUdUOSTwqUABGn@Xv6u1mCmt5s/l7dbdmpBVnp@gUJxekFifhZIRWIWl6IiBAHN0tT8DwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 80 bytes

```
s=list(input())
n=0
print(end="!")
for x in s:
    print(s[n],end="!")
    n=n+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9g2J7O4RCMzr6C0RENTkyvP1oCroCgzr0QjNS/FVklRSZMrLb9IoUIhM0@h2IpLAQgg0sXRebE6cDUg8TzbPG3D//8NFYwUjBVMFEwVzAA)

Comment: You do not need `n`, as you can reference to the `n`th item in the list by using the variable `x` (Remove `n` completely and change `s[n]` to `x`).

Answer (score 0):

## ARM Thumb machine code, 12 bytes

```
21 22 08 c8 0c c1 00 2b fb d1 70 47
```

Assembly source:

```c
    .syntax unified
    .arch armv7-a
    .thumb
    .thumb_func
    .globl insert_between
// input: r0: pointer to null terminated UTF-32LE string
//        r1: pointer to buffer
// output: null terminated UTF-32LE string at *r1
// C callable prototype:
//   void insert_between(const char32_t *in, char32_t *out);
insert_between:
    // Put '!' in a register for later
    movs   r2, #'!'
.Lloop:
    // Load char from pointer, advance pointer
    ldmia  r0!, {r3}                          @ tmp = *in++;
    // Store '!' then the char from the pointer.
    // The null terminator will be included,
    // which also adds the trailing '!'.
    stmia  r1!, {r2, r3}                      @ *out++ = '!', *out++ = tmp;
    // Loop if r3 wasn't a null terminator
    cmp    r3, #0
    bne    .Lloop
    // return
    bx     lr
```

Callable from C with the following prototype:

```c
void insert_between(const char32_t *in, char32_t *out);
```

As with most of my Thumb string solutions, everything is null terminated UTF-32 thanks to `ldmia` and `stmia` being the only narrow instructions to load and advance a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 18 bytes

```
'!'orl0=?;o'!'o40.
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiJyEnb3JsMD0/O28nISdvNDAuIiwiaW5wdXQiOiIiLCJzdGFjayI6Ikluc2VydCIsInN0YWNrX2Zvcm1hdCI6ImNoYXJzIiwiaW5wdXRfZm9ybWF0IjoibnVtYmVycyJ9)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
""'!v
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWS5WU1BXLlhQnJRdDRRZs9MwrTi0qUcjMU0hKLSlPTc2DSAAA)

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
'!j'!ṛ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWK9QVs9QVH-6cvaQ4KbkYKrhgo2decWpRiUJmnkJSakl5amoeRAIA)

##### Explanations

```
""'!v  # Implicit input
    v  # Replace...
""     # ...the empty string...
  '!   # ...with "!" in the input
       # Implicit output
```

```
'!j'!ṛ  # Implicit input
'!j     # Join by "!"
   '!ṛ  # Surround by "!"
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 25 bytes

```rust
|s:&str|s.replace("","!")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVDLasMwEKRH6St2dSg2uIU8KQk9leQQB5x7MEXUkomdxqrWOTX5kl5yaP-gl_5Kv6ZrmUAlhh1md0diPj79kdrLtz3Aq94dohjepdibFiw8fh1be_fwc6LZLbX-RPfeuL1-MZFSiUIV9_3fmycxl8I2HraUgDeUw-4AWylEB6EGMIQRjGECU5UEBQcIOGSMGGPGhDFFxc08ue55pakAbasmBV3PjKw3fl1I4GOzVbaYB5ouM5kua-OqsnFApdNN1U3oqn_LK9RIWPADGi1W2GAaeI0zNCi5btDjmick6_21mOGKscD5PzXFJWsy1Jp3HbuV7Oe4R8wcuzasXT008_CJXIq8i1VoIuPbZ_OGkY0oDmHFnN1ZnvssL5e-_gE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Marbles](https://github.com/vxgmichel/marbles), 2087 bytes

An elegant 25 x 31 grid of 774 characters:

```
○══════════════════════╗
║○═══════════════════╗ ║
║║○════════════════╗ ║ ║
║║║○═════════════╗ ║ ║ ║
║║║║○══════════╗ ║ ║ ║ ║
║║║║║○═══════╗ ║ ║ ║ ║ ║
║║║║║║○════╗ ║ ║ ║ ║ ║ ║
║║║║║║║○═╗ ║ ║ ║ ║ ║ ║ ║
║║║║║║║║○╜○╜○╜○╜○╜○╜○╜○╜
║║║║║║║║ ┃ ║ ║ ║ ║ ┃ ║ ║
║║║║║║║║◆╢◆╢◆╢◆╢◆╢◆╢◆╢◆╢
║║║║║║║║ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃
║║║║║║║║◇╢◇╢◇╢◇╢◇╢◇╢◇╢◇╢
║║║║║║║║○╬═╬═╬═╬═╬═╬═╬╗║
║║║║║║║║║║╔╬╗║╔╬╗║╔╬╗║║║
║║║║║║║║╓╢╙╢╓╢╙╢╓╢╙╢╓╢╙╢
║║║║║║║║╚╬╝║╚╬╝║╚╬╝║╚╬╝║
║║║║║║║║○╜○╜○╜○╜○╜○╜○╜○╜
║║║║║║║║ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃
║║║║║║║║◇╜◇╜◇╜◇╜◇╜◇╜◇╜◇╜
║║║║║║║║◆╢◆╢◆╢◆╢◆╢◆╢◆╢◆╢
║║║║║║║║ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃
║║║║║║║║◇╢◇╢◇╢◇╢◇╢◇╢◇╢◇╢
║║║║║║║╚═╝ ║ ║ ║ ║ ║ ║ ║
║║║║║║╚════╝ ║ ║ ║ ║ ║ ║
║║║║║╚═══════╝ ║ ║ ║ ║ ║
║║║║╚══════════╝ ║ ║ ║ ║
║║║╚═════════════╝ ║ ║ ║
║║╚════════════════╝ ║ ║
║╚═══════════════════╝ ║
╚══════════════════════╝
```

Marbles is not available on [tio.run](https://tio.run) yet but the test examples can be run using [marbles.py](https://github.com/vxgmichel/marbles#simulation):

```shell
± echo test | ./marbles.py exclamation.txt --quiet --no-display
!t!e!s!t!
!
```

Ungolfed version:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║  ╔════════════════════════════════════════════╗  ║
║  ║  ╔══════════════════════════════════════╗  ║  ║
║  ║  ║  ╔════════════════════════════════╗  ║  ║  ║
║  ║  ║  ║  ╔══════════════════════════╗  ║  ║  ║  ║
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ╔════════════════════╗  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ╔══════════════╗  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║    ┓ 8 marbles representing a byte
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ╔════════○  ○  ○  ○  ○  ○  ○  ○    ┛ This is the main variable
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║        ╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗  ┓
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║        ╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝  ┃
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║     ○══╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╗ ┃ Synchronization
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║     ║  ╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗║ ┃ Right-most marble exits first
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║     ║  ╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝║ ┃
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║     ╚══╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╝ ┛
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║        ╙○ ╙○ ╙○ ╙○ ╙○ ╙○ ╙○ ╙○   ┓ Set value to 0x21
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║        ║  ║  ┃  ║  ║  ║  ║  ┃    ┛ (the ascii character '!')
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║        ╟◆ ╟◆ ╟◆ ╟◆ ╟◆ ╟◆ ╟◆ ╟◆   ┓
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║        ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃    ┃ Write the byte to stdout
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║        ╟◇ ╟◇ ╟◇ ╟◇ ╟◇ ╟◇ ╟◇ ╟◇   ┃ LSB is on the right
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║        ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃    ┛
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║        ╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗  ┓
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║        ╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝  ┃
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║     ○══╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╗ ┃ Synchronization
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║     ║  ╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗╚═╗║ ┃ Right-most marble exits first
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║     ║  ╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝╔╤╝║ ┃
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║     ╚══╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╬╛═╝ ┛
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║        ╙○ ╙○ ╙○ ╙○ ╙○ ╙○ ╙○ ╙○   ┓ Read a byte from stdin
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║        ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃    ┃ LSB is on the right
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║        ╙◇ ╙◇ ╙◇ ╙◇ ╙◇ ╙◇ ╙◇ ╙◇   ┛
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║        ╟◆ ╟◆ ╟◆ ╟◆ ╟◆ ╟◆ ╟◆ ╟◆   ┓
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║        ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃    ┃ Write the byte to stdout
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║        ╟◇ ╟◇ ╟◇ ╟◇ ╟◇ ╟◇ ╟◇ ╟◇   ┃ LSB is on the right
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║        ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃  ┃    ┛
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ╚════════╝  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ╚══════════════╝  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║
║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ╚════════════════════╝  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║
║  ║  ║  ║  ╚══════════════════════════╝  ║  ║  ║  ║
║  ║  ║  ╚════════════════════════════════╝  ║  ║  ║
║  ║  ╚══════════════════════════════════════╝  ║  ║
║  ╚════════════════════════════════════════════╝  ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

This is the first [marbles](https://github.com/vxgmichel/marbles) submission ever :)