# N-Dimensional Cartesian Product

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, set-theory

## Introduction

The Cartesian product of two lists is calculated by iterating over every element in the first and second list and outputting points. This is not a very good definition, so here are some examples: the Cartesian product of `[1, 2]` and `[3, 4]` is `[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]`. The product of `[1]` and `[2]` is `[(1, 2)]`. However, no one said you could only use two lists. The product of `[1, 2]`, `[3, 4]`, and `[5, 6]` is `[(1, 3, 5), (1, 4, 5), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 6), (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5), (2, 3, 6), (2, 4, 6)]`.

## Challenge

Given a number of lists, your program must output the Cartesian product of the lists given.

- You can assume that there will always be more than 1 list, and that each list will have the same length. No list will ever be empty. If your language has no method of stdin, you may take input from command line arguments or a variable.
- Your program must output the Cartesian product of all the input lists. If your language has no stdout, you may store output in a variable or as a     return value. The output should be a list of lists, or any other iterable type.

## Example I/O

> Input: `[1, 2] [3, 4]`
> Output: `[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]`
>
> Input: `[1, 2] [3, 4] [5, 6]`
> Output: `[(1, 3, 5), (1, 4, 5), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 6), (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5), (2, 3, 6), (2, 4, 6)]`
>
> Input: `[1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6]`
> Output: `[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]`

## Rules

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: boring answer: `itertools.product` in python

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125104/cartesian-product-of-two-lists), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/165664/cartesian-product-of-a-list-with-itself-n-times).

Comment: _If your language has no method of stdin, you may take input from command line arguments or a variable_ I suggest you allow command-line inputs without any condition. See [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10003/36398)

Comment: Does order matter among the output lists?

Comment: Order does not matter @xnor.

Comment: Is it mandatory to have an output in the format `[[a,b,c],[a,c,b],...]` (in any order), or are other formats also allowed? The two Japt answers output as `[a,b,c,a,c,b,...]` and `[[[a,b],c], [[a,c],b], ...]` instead for example (not sure if this is a valid output)?

Comment: No, the format described is not mandatory @KevinCruijssen

Answer (score 12):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 1 byte

Courtesy of [ngn](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52583691#52583691)

```
{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03B1kqh@n9qcka@QpqCoYKRtbGCCReYq66rq6vOhSpjbapghl1WwdjaRAEo@x8A)

'tis called [Catalogue](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/curlylf)…

Comment: You beat me to it :).  I think `,@{` would be more fair though, since the output of naked `{` doesn't have a uniform structure (ie, it depends on the inputs).

Comment: @Jonah [Jelly gives the same structure.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195965/43319)

Comment: results not seem list deep 1 of element of input

Comment: @RosLuP It is. J's [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03B1kqh@n9qcka@go@eQpqCoYKRtbGCyX8A "J – Try It Online") `L.` is APL's `≡`.

Answer (score 10):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 7 bytes

```hs
mapM id
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPzexwFchMwVIZ@Yp2Cqk5HMpAEFBUWZeiYKKQppCdLShjoJRrI5CtLGOgklsLH5pIG2qo2CGQ5mOgjFIhYmOAkTR/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA)

### Built-in, 8 bytes

```hs
sequence
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzvzi1sDQ1Lzn1f25iZp6CrUJKPpcCEBQUZeaVKKgopClERxvqKBjF6ihEG@somMTG4pcG0qY6CmY4lOkoGINUmOgoQBT9/5eclpOYXvxfN7mgAAA)

### Less boring, 33 bytes

Out-golfed by [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195977). Go upvote that instead!

```hs
f[]=[[]]
f(h:t)=[i:j|i<-h,j<-f t]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/Py061jY6OjaWK00jw6pE0zY60yqrJtNGN0Mny0Y3TaEk9n9uYmaegq1CSj6XAhAUFGXmlSioKKQpREcb6igYxeooRBvrKJgATcArDaRNdRTMcCjTUTAGqTDRUYAo@g8A)

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 23 bytes

```hs
foldr((<*>).map(:))[[]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPy0/J6VIQ8NGy05TLzexQMNKUzM6Ojb2f25iZp6CrUJKPpcCEBQUZeaVKKgopClERxvqKBjF6ihEG@somMTG4pcG0qY6CmY4lOkoGINUmOgoQBT9/5eclpOYXvxfN7mgAAA)

Without using `mapM` or `sequence` or the like.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 56 bytes

```python
def f(M,*l):M and[f(M[1:],*l,x)for x in M[0]]or print(l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc4xDoMwDAXQGU7hLaT6Q2loB@6QE1geaNOoSCggxBBOnxoxdOjg4b8/fC/79pmTKyW8I8XG4zLZ3tOQAmvithcVZBvnlTKNiTxfRTQs65i2ZrLlaPzRMJvh@TIwQS/vRqDUgm4CdqBO/gB8Bz1@DnJqHehk6etKn7B1dY7Z8gU)

No itertools. This is one of those weird functions that prints. Thanks to  Unrelated String for -2 bytes with `def`.

Comment: Since the return value doesn't matter, you can shave two bytes off by using `def`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc4xDoMwDAXQGU7hLaT6Q2loB@6QE1geaNOoSCggxBBOnxoxdOjg4b8/fC/79pmTKyW8I8XG4zLZ3tOQAmvithcVZBvnlTKNiTxfRTQs65i2ZrLlaPzRMJvh@TIwQS/vRqDUgm4CdqBO/gB8Bz1@DnJqHehk6etKn7B1dY7Z8gU "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @ChasBrown I don't think that's allowed, it nests the output a lot. And unfortunately Python doesn't do iterable unpacking in comprehensions.

Comment: @xnor : quite right! Carry on...

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

A simple reduction by Cartesian product.

```
rï
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=cu8&input=W1sxLDJdLFszLDRdLFs1LDZdXQ)

Comment: Lol!  Congrats! You preceded me by 12 minutes ! Anyway I'm really proud of .. I immediately thought about that solution

Comment: Ha, I spent 15 minutes looking through Japt docs and couldn't find this again. Lol

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, here it is "pretty printed": https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=cu8&input=W1sxLDJdLFszLDRdLFs1LDZdXQotUQ

Comment: OP stated the output-format is indeed flexible, and those outputs are allowed.

Comment: Thanks, @KevinCruijssen. I've updated to Japt `-R` anyway.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>60</s> 59 bytes

```python
f=lambda A,*x:[[v]+u for v in A for u in x and f(*x)or[[]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY29DoIwFIVnfYqzVfAuAjqQMPQ5bu5QbBpJtBACpDx9Lf7EweEk3/nOcIZ1uvW@iNE1d/NorYGmPNTMixxnuH7Egs5Dv3DeMMB4C3fIQ9aPzCISt01vG7My7VWRsilhVUJJnQiFEJeESv4E8Zlw@XlCmVxFeGtIvd8NY@cn6C@ka519SnwC)

1 byte thx to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs).

Look Ma! No `itertools`!

Comment: [59 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY29DoIwFIVnfYqzVfAuAjqQMPQ5bu5QbBpJtBACpDx9Lf7EweEk3/nOcIZ1uvW@iNE1d/NorYGmPNTMixxnuH7Egs5Dv3DeMMB4C3fIQ9aPzCISt01vG7My7VWRsilhVUJJnQiFEJeESv4E8Zlw@XlCmVxFeGtIvd8NY@cn6C@ka519SnwC)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>4</s> 2 bytes

```
Œp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIL/h9sfNa3JAmIQatynoxAJ5jfuO7Tt0Lb//6O5OKOjDXUUjGJ1FKKNdRRMYmN1MISAtKmOghmSlI6CMUjUREcBTQJDD5A211GwANGWOgoGIKWxAA)

Output is "pretty printed" in the TIO link

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 1 byte

```
ẋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3w/@Gu7v//oxWiow11FIxidaKNdRRMYmN10AR0ok11FMwQ4joKxkAxEx0FiLBCLAA)

A slightly less boring [generator](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/10753#10753) solution:

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
∋ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6OmpofbFjzc1Vn7cOuE/486ukHU/2iF6GhDHQWjWJ1oYx0Fk9hYHTQBnWhTHQUzhLiOgjFQzERHASKsEAsA)

Comment: A careful reading of the rules suggests that function submissions are only allowed to output through return values if printing is impossible, so if that's actually enforced, +1 byte to the first for `w`, and +2 to the second for `ẉ⊥`.

Answer (score 4):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>31</s> 15 bytes

```
{x@'/:+!(#:)'x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qusJBXd9KW1FD2UpTvaL2f5q6hoahgpG1sYKJpjWMZW2qYAbhKRhbmyiAeJr/AQ)

Comment: How are you finding K compared with J?  What have you been using to learn it?

Comment: @Jonah I can't compare them directly. K lacks J's math capabilities, but works on heterogeneous lists. It is much more compact and I like it very much even I have only sctratched the surface. I started learning from the [oK Manual](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok/blob/gh-pages/docs/Manual.md). On several occasions `ngn` helped me in [thr k tree](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90748/the-k-tree). He also supplied  almost all my previos k submissions with golfing tips.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>8</s> 4 bytes

```perl6
&[X]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfLToi9r81V3FipUKaQrShjlGsTrSxjgmQNNUxi/0PAA)

Simple reduce by cross product. <s>It would be nice if I could return the meta-operator by itself, but I've never figured out how to do that.</s> Turns out it works for cross product?

Comment: [`&[X]` seems to work](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfLToi9r81V3FipUKaQrShjlGsTrSxjgmQNNUxi/0PAA) in this case.

Comment: @nwellnhof What? But `&[+]` doesn't work? I don't understand when it does and doesn't work

Comment: Seems to be an [implementation detail of the infix operators](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVJBLy8xN1VHQd1KQV1HQS@xKLMEKKanoJecX5pXopCWX6SgFq0dqwMktcBkHZiMiP3/HwA). Some infix operators accept more than two args but it's not a requirement.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 20 bytes

```
->i,*j{i.product *j}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5TRyurOlOvoCg/pTS5REErq/Z/QVFmXolCml5yYk6ORrShjoJRrI5CtLGOgkmsJldBaUmxgpISFx5FQNpUR8EMr2IdBWOQOhMdBYjS/wA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>54</s> <s>39</s> 32 bytes

This took really long to write (as I tried to golf it too) (unsurprisingly, all the golfing ideas only appeared after I finally posted this). Takes input as a list of strings of alphanumeric characters and underscores (whatever `\w` matches in your universe), each preceded by a semicolon (I assume characters are as acceptable in Retina as numbers are in everything else; in fact, the challenge never actually specified numbers).
Outputs the list of the resulting strings, each preceded by a comma.

```
^
,
+w`,(\w*)[^;]*;\w*(\w)
,$1$2
```

Explanation:

```
^                       match the beginning of the string
,                       add a comma there
+w`,(\w*)[^;]*;\w*(\w)  solve the rest of the problem
,$1$2                   replace with a comma, group 1 and group 2
```

The third and fourth lines are in a convergence loop (run until no change) (declared by the `+`). The regular expression in the 3rd line works on lines like `, ac, bc, ad, bd;ef;gh` and matches all substrings starting at a comma and ending at a character after the first semicolon, where the group 1 is the string after the comma and group 2 is the last character.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/P45Lh0u7PEFHI6ZcSzM6zjpWyxrIAvI0uXRUDFWM/v@3TkyyTk6xTk2zTs8AAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>54</s> 47 bytes

```r
f=function(x)split(j<-expand.grid(x),1:nrow(j))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P802rTQvuSQzP0@jQrO4ICezRCPLRje1oiAxL0UvvSgzBSisY2iVV5RfrpGlqfm/oCgzr0RDKbXCUEmTC8JJ08jJLC7RMLQy0jG2MtHUhIkDFRnhUKRjamWGotAYU6GxjglY0X8A)

If you consider data.frame rows iterable:

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 27 bytes

```r
f=function(x)expand.grid(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P802rTQvuSQzP0@jQjO1oiAxL0UvvSgzBcj7X1CUmVeioZRaYaikyQXhpGnkZBaXaBhaGekYW5loasLEgYqMcCjSMbUyQ1FojKnQWMcErOg/AA)

Comment: You don't need to include the `f=` in the byte count here, and can include it in the header: [Example](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQjO1oiAxL0UvvSgzBcj7X1CUmVeioZRaYaikyQXhpGnkZBaXaBhaGekYW5loasLEgYqMcCjSMbUyQ1FojKnQWMcErOg/AA "R – Try It Online")

. 
Also, as `expand.grid` is a built-in, this is basically 11 bytes as `expand.grid` returns the function. I think we've scored them as such in the past, though am happy to be corrected by someone with more intimate knowledge of practice.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3 (Cython)](http://cython.org/), <s>46</s> <s>44</s> 31 bytes

```python
__import__('itertools').product
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM9ZNBtP/0xRsFWL@x8dn5hbkF5XEx2uoZ5akFpXk5@cUq2vqFRTlp5Qml/wvKMrMK9HQStOINtRRMIrVUYg21lEwAdGmOgpmsZqa/wE)

This doesn't need more explanation, right?

(-13 bytes thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king); -2 bytes thanks to [caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing))

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unnamed lambdas are perfectly acceptable here, so you can remove the `f=` to save two bytes.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thank you!  I have removed the `f=`.  I'm not sure how to make TIO count this as 44 bytes though ...

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##HcZJCoAgFADQq/xdGhY0LoJOYiKNJFRf7Ad2ehtW79mbVjyKZPwNC7TQha3fh6kH32htdouOtGaRodkR4nZGPLUOp2skFnserDPHu4VJmQnIlQBZCCg/KwG1UpyHBw) should work

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thanks!  Didn't know that the backslash works here.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 6 bytes

```
Tuples
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P6S0ICe1@H9AUWZeSbSyrl1atHJsrJqCvoNCNZeCgkJ1taGOglGtjkK1sY6CSW2tDhZBIG2qo2CGIqmjYAwSN9FRgEhx1f4HAA)

Answer (score 2):

### Julia 1.0, 34 bytes

No imports used, iterators in Base has this. It actually makes a lazy form of this, but to print them all it will collect each one.

```
println.(Iterators.product(l...))
```

where l is the list of lists.

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 30 bytes

```sh
for l;a=($^a\ ${^${=l}})
<<<$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moanxPy2/SCHHOtFWQyUuMUZBpTpOpdo2p7ZWk8vGxkYl8b8mF1eagrqhgpG6grqxggmQNFUwU/8PAA)

Split `=` and cartesian product `^` for each element. Our base case adds an extra space, which cleanly separates our output lists.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.»â
```

Outputs `[[a,b],[c,d],[d,e]]` in the format `[[[a,c],d], [[a,c],e], ...]`. To output in the format `[[a,[c,d]], [a,[c,e]], ...]`, replace the `»` with `«`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f79Duw4v@/4@ONtQxitWJNtYxAZKmOmZA0lzHIjYWAA) or [try it online with right- instead of left-reduce](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f79Dqw4v@/4@ONtQxitWJNtYxAZKmOmZA0lzHIjYWAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
.»   # (Left-)reduce by (or right-reduce with `.«`):
  â  #  Taking the cartesian product of the two lists
     # (after which the resulting list is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 1 byte

```
Π
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fm18erPOoqfH/uQX///@Pjo421DGK1Yk21jGJBVJIPJ1oUx0zmJiOMZBhogMWiQUA) `Π` takes the Cartesian product of a list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 52 bytes

Returns a list of lists.

```javascript
f=([a,...b],o=[])=>a?a.flatMap(x=>f(b,[...o,x])):[o]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fcoxDsIwDADAnVd4TCRjibYwIKW8oC@wPLilQaCormiF@vsQBkaYbrmHvnQZnvd53U92HXOOwbEiEfWCFlh8aPWiFJOunc5uC210PXIJhpt4f2aTPNi0WBop2c1Fx3xAqASBa4RGStr9DcUjwulnRKg/p0H4tvwG)

---

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 52 bytes

Prints the results.

```javascript
f=([a,...b],o)=>a?a.map(x=>f(b,o?o+[,x]:x)):print(o)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcrBCsIwDIDhu0@RY4KxMDdFNro9SMghEwoTtGWO0bevDr3p6T/8381We17nKS2H9VJK8CjGzrlROZLvbTB3t4TZ9wFHjkPcC2dtM1Gb5umxYKQSUKRiOCqD1AyNKnXwudTtfu67J4bzf8VQb6Bh@JryAg)

Answer (score 1):

## Erlang, 57 bytes

```
c([]) -> [[]];
c([H|T]) -> [[X|Y] || X <- H, Y <- c(T)].
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
rï
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=cu8&input=WwogWzEsMl0sCiBbMyw0XSwKIFs1LDZdCl0KLVE)

```
Reduces input by combination with initial value of 1st element
```

Duplicate of @Shaggy  answer, I was solving this while he just posted the same solution. I hope I can leave my answer too because it's awesome

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 22 bytes

```
ＩＥΠＥθＬιＥθ§λ÷ιΠ∨Ｅ…θμＬν¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYwxC8IwFIT/yhtf4DlUq4uT6FKwtHvIEJJgH8REYyz@@0i0essdx31nJp1M1L6UMXHIeNSPjL2@4ZiifZpvvhOcXbjkCVkIQbB0h9wF617oCbqQTzyzdcgEP3RIH7qP3tb5VfxvQn1pxKJ9KVLKhmCtCOSGoK2@Jdgppcpq9m8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    θ                   Input list
   Ｅ                    Map over elements
      ι                 Current element
     Ｌ                  Length
  Π                     Product
 Ｅ                      Map over implicit range
        θ               Input list
       Ｅ                Map over elements
          λ             Current element
         §              Cyclically indexed by
            ι           Outer index
           ÷            Integer divide
                 θ      Input list
                …       Truncated to length
                  μ     Inner index
               Ｅ        Map over elements
                    ν   Current element
                   Ｌ    Length
              ∨      ¹  Replace empty list with literal 1
             Π          Product
Ｉ                       Cast to string
                        Implicitly print double-spaced on separate lines
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), chars 11, bytes 22

```
{,↑(∘.,)/⍵}
```

test for product of sets:

```
  f←{,↑(∘.,)/⍵}
  ⎕fmt (1 2)(3 4)
┌2────────────┐
│┌2───┐ ┌2───┐│
││ 1 2│ │ 3 4││
│└~───┘ └~───┘2
└∊────────────┘
  ⎕fmt f (1 2)(3 4)
┌4──────────────────────────┐
│┌2───┐ ┌2───┐ ┌2───┐ ┌2───┐│
││ 1 3│ │ 1 4│ │ 2 3│ │ 2 4││
│└~───┘ └~───┘ └~───┘ └~───┘2
└∊──────────────────────────┘
  ⎕fmt f (1 2)(3 4)(5 6)
┌8──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│┌3─────┐ ┌3─────┐ ┌3─────┐ ┌3─────┐ ┌3─────┐ ┌3─────┐ ┌3─────┐ ┌3─────┐│
││ 1 3 5│ │ 1 3 6│ │ 1 4 5│ │ 1 4 6│ │ 2 3 5│ │ 2 3 6│ │ 2 4 5│ │ 2 4 6││
│└~─────┘ └~─────┘ └~─────┘ └~─────┘ └~─────┘ └~─────┘ └~─────┘ └~─────┘2
└∊──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
  ≢f (1 2)(3 4)(5 6)
8
  f (⍳3)(4 5 6)
 1 4  1 5  1 6  2 4  2 5  2 6  3 4  3 5  3 6 

  ⎕fmt f (4 5 6)
┌1───────┐
│┌3─────┐│
││ 4 5 6││
│└~─────┘2
└∊───────┘
```

Answer (score -1):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 136 bytes

```python
import re
from itertools import*
print(list(product(*[[int(i) for i in i.split(', ')] for i in re.findall(r'\[([0-9, ]+)\]',input())])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RckxDsIwDEDRvafwFruECiggOEvIgGgrLKVx5LoDpw8gBqYvvV9e9pTcX4rWynMRNdCxmVRmYBvVRNICv9E2RTkbJl4Mi8qwPgzbEL7GBJMoMHAG7paS2NB5cBT/rmM3cR7uKaG6W8Cw2149xA3dovOcy2pIFImo1rD3cIgQeg/HT04ezvEN)

Comment: You don't have to do any of the string processing. You could just take input as a list of lists: *"Given a number of lists"*

Comment: The heart of this answer is just itertools.product too.